# Flag 'Try This: {code}' Answers as "Very Low Quality"?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, low-quality-posts

I constantly tell people that “try this” is not a good answer. It explains nothing and just dumps code on the OP which does not teach anything.

It's becoming worse and worse, and I even see very high rep uses (ranging from 5k to even 100K+) posting these bad answers.

Is flagging these answers as “Very Low Quality” proper or should I just continue downvoting and commenting why “try this” is a bad answer (which I'm honestly getting tired of).

Comment: You don't have to comment you know.

Comment: some (maybe even most) of such posts get automatic VLQ flag from [quality-filter](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255054/why-do-so-many-code-snippet-answers-get-flagged-as-low-quality)

Comment: This reminded me to ask a related question I'd been kicking around about the review side of this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256361/should-i-be-concerned-about-delete-reviews-on-reasonable-but-brief-answers , so thanks for asking.

Comment: @BoltClock I know that I don't have to, but it's all I can do to try and improve answers from people. I hope it's not a futile effort but if I can get even one person to improve their answers I feel like I've made a good difference.

Comment: If an SO user can't think of anything better than a "try this" answer then the problem is usually a question that's entirely too vague.

Comment: "Is flagging these answers as "Very Low Quality" proper" No, they aren't very low quality.

Comment: @Hans Passant: There are plenty of clear, specific questions that get "try this" answers. From what I've seen the problem lies in the answer more often than the question. For example there are many users who *habitually* begin every one of their answers with "Try this" regardless of how well-written the question is or if the question is even asking for a solution in the first place.

Comment: @BoltClock They (esp high rep users) feel rather bad when downvoted without a comment.  I've seen it so often that I was [tempted to ask](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive) and it seemed to emerge that people expect clarifications when downvoted.  (Upvoting incorrect answers seems fine, though.)

Comment: "Try this" followed by code that is a poor guess at what might be an answer would be poor quality. "Try this" followed by code that is understandable, obvious once you see it, and correct, is not poor quality. "Try this" followed by code that will help figuring out the actual problem is often good quality.

Comment: Interesting. "Try this" is suggested as being prima facie flaggable because sufficient explanation of the supplied code is not included. However, downvotes (which in my experience generally come without a comment) or flagging as "low quality" are suggested as a proper response, which provides little feedback to the poster of the "try this" answer. ?????

Comment: Within a minute of reading this question [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909689/regex-replace-last-occurence-of-word-between-2-words/23909861#23909861) popped up from a 49k user. Regex is voodoo at the best of times, answers like that *really* benefit from an explanation...

Comment: We've been told that "looks good" in the VLQ queue actually means "looks vaguely like an answer, even if not an answer to the question", so 10/10 times I'd be hitting "looks good" on an answer you flagged.

Comment: When i post 'try this code' answers, i make sure there are always *comments* in my code. if there are comments in a 'try this' answer i don't think these answers are bad because they do provide information

Comment: Surely the content of the post is what matters, not whether it has the words "Try this" prepended or not.

Comment: What everyone else said, plus: Very Low Quality flags are not a particularly useful kind of flag when on the moderator dashboard. I’m still not clear on whether the ones that were “automatically flagged based on length and whatnot” (they generally aren’t, either) show up there.

Comment: @false: VLQ basically means "unsalvageable."  It doesn't apply to "try this {code}" answers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Nobody uses it for “unsalvageable”, though.

Comment: I agree with the overall consent that such questions should not be flagged as VLQ. However, I believe that 99% of these answers are not helpful. For the OP, I imagine it being like going to a store, asking for a tool, and the customer support just puts something in your hand and runs away. Then you are standing there, wondering how that magically device in your hands works and how you'd use it to solve your problem. IMO a good answer consists of an explanation of the answer and *the problem* (if unclear to the OP, which is more often the case than it is not).

Comment: There are two different issues here that are being conflated. "Try this" often means "I don't know whether this will work, but I'm taking a wild guess". I strongly object to these answers, and frequently downvote them, because I believe that Stack Overflow should be a "question and answer" site, not a "question and wild guess" site. But there are other cases where a code snippet is so clear that it warrants no further explanation - the code speaks for itself and answers the question completely. This latter (unfortunately very small) group should not be tarred with the same brush as the first.

Comment: If the OP can't learn anything by reading some code, they're not trying hard enough.

Comment: Everybody posts try this answers, a [sample from yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23378222/2530848), It all depends on **time** they have. Remember not all the people are working for stackoverflow. I post try this kind of answers, but that doesn't mean I won't explain when op asks for any clarification.

Comment: There is a difference between the "Well, you might try discombobulating the framitz" answer to a head-scratcher question ("Why does my app cause red iPhones to catch fire?"), and a "Try this:  `x = y + z;` answer when the OP is struggling to understand a concept (and when the answerer generally hasn't got a very good grasp on the concept either).

Comment: **You should get a job. That will keep you busy enough not to ask this kind of questions.** Or a pet. Some responsibility to shift your focus from the bad answers that haunt you.

Comment: It seems that for many people it isn't really the code only answer that is the problem for perceiving it as low quality, it is the "try this" introduction. It makes the poster sound lazy and sounds like "I don't know if this works, it just came to my mind, just try it out it might help you". Much better would probably some "this should work" or "do it like this" or "this worked for me" or similar

Comment: @CodeAngry I have a full time job and 2 dogs actually ;)

Comment: I oft times have try this with a response of explanation after code. But sometime the question doesn't need an explanation more than just fixing the problem.

Comment: When I come accross an answer whose only content is _try this: X_, I'm inclined to think that it should rather be a comment but an answer, like _have you tried X?_. From my opinion it lacks an explanation about _why the answerer thinks his approach should work_. Unfortunately code doesn't fit nicely into the comments section, though.

Comment: Maybe we need a "normal low quality" queue. I really start to get annoyed by answers that change [1 (!) character in code blocks that are 6 lines long](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29093104/457406). And instead of "you did that wrong" all I see is "try this". I don't want to use a fucking diff tool to see what the answer wants to tell me. /rant

Comment: It should be a valid VLQ flag in my opinion.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

No, it is not appropriate to flag such a post.  While you may feel that those answers are not quality answers, they are not of sufficiently low quality to merit *deletion*.  As such, there will be nothing for the users evaluating the VLQ flag to do except dismiss the flag.

When you come across an answer that you feel is not helpful due to its low quality, you should downvote it.  That is the appropriate response here.  Flagging is just wasting a bunch of people's time.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You seem to have missed the main point of the answer, and the question as well.  The question is whether these posts should be flagged as VLQ.  They should not.  Doing so is not appropriate, as it won't accomplish anything.  The only appropriate action that you're *allowed* to take is to downvote (or comment).  If you don't want to do that, or don't think it will help, then that's fine, so long as you aren't flagging the post inappropriately.

Comment: yeah, I know. Most SO folks tend to answer the question literally, caring not for the problem behind it. And take pride for it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense And yet your answer to what you consider the real problem is that there's nothing anyone can do, the sky is falling, and you should just give up on life.  That's not particularly productive (regardless of how true it is).  Its not actually helping solve the problem in any way.

Comment: It does. I've been writing this kind of answers for years and finally we've got that magic hammer for one of the core SO problems. Hopefully, others will be solved eventually, despite of all the conformists lobby

Comment: whats worse? a low quality answer that solves the problem or an answer that solves the problem that was deleted. When presented with that it should be obvious why flagging them for deletion is pyrrhic at best, idiotic at worst. But then common sense has been shown to be ignorant so many times its a wonder we enlightened beasts listen to it at all.

Comment: @JohnNicholas It depends- which of the two is more likely to have somebody else come in and write a good answer?

Comment: @BenAaronson id suggest odds are v low for both. If you don't ask a question that has already been asked on here i find i figure it out for myself 2 weeks later before i get an answer these days. so correct low quality answers must be preferable to no answer. After all if you have such a problem edit it ... or answer it properly yourself - THEN mark the other otherwise you are just destroying something useful without improving it. The point of stack overflow is answering questions not perfection. At a time when  BIG question about SO is why so negative/crappy tudes - issues like this annoy

Comment: @BenAaronson btw i am not talking about speculative answers, burn them to the ground. I am talking about deleting correct answers.

Comment: @JohnNicholas I do agree with your ultimate conclusion, not to delete the answers. I'm just not sure I agree with this particular reasoning. I'd guess if somebody crunched the numbers that questions with green ticks get a lot less activity from potential answerers (as opposed to other people with the same question) than those without.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, that's more or less in line with the point I was making. Again though, I think that on balance, that doesn't justify deleting correct answers.

Comment: @pnuts also that someone has found this with the ability to provide a better answer is self evident or else the question of whether to delete would not of arisen. IT is the person who wants to delete the answer that has the responsibility to provide a better answer. Then flag it, raise it in chat and someone will upvote.

Comment: Besides downvote, I think you can edit the answer.  If the code is correct and it needs an explanation, add something to it.  The original answerer gets a message on your edit.  Often they will thank you for the edit; English/prose may not be their strong point.

Comment: @artlessnoise Most people are (rightly) wary of making substantial changes to another person's answer. Plus there's very little reason not to post their own answer, with accompanying explanation, and receive the benefits of the upvotes that explanation generally attracts over the long term.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist  It is not the right choice in all cases, but it is an option.  Especially, if you don't care about points, but correct information.

Comment: @artlessnoise It usually is *not* an option.  That would be a radical change to the post, and not an appropriate edit.  The *appropriate* action in that context is to post a new answer, given that you're contributing significant amount of *content* to the answer, and not improving the presentation of the authors existing content.

Comment: To me, they _are_ "of sufficiently low quality to merit deletion". They are unhelpful both to OP and future readers: they don't explain what the problem is or how to solve it next time (or what are the implication of the provided solution). Bah, they don't even guarantee that they solve this particular problem, either ("try this"="maybe it'll help, I dunno")! Fixing these problems is equivalent to writing one's own answer since these things require at least, the same (if not better) understanding of the problem domain.

Comment: It's also helpful to explain why you downvoted their answer instead of *only* downvoting their answer. That gives the person answering the question time to fix it with some idea of what they need to do in order to stay within compliant levels of quality. If you're doing these in mass, even a link to the help-center is better than nothing.

Comment: Why are they not of sufficiently low quality to merit deletion?

Comment: @MilesRout Largely because their quality is a matter of opinion; a judgement call to be made by subject matter experts.  Deletion is for content that *isn't even an answer* or is so unambiguously harmful, even to someone with no knowledge of the subject matter at hand (think for example spam or abusive/offensive content).  There is a tool put in place to handle answers that simply aren't quality answers, from a technical perspective, and that's voting.

Comment: Code only answers are low quality, according to this failed review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15751857. From now on, to me they just fall into the "Skip" category.

Comment: @Rodia If you don't want to review bad posts from the review queue, and just want to skip them, then why are you using the review queue in the first place?

Comment: I skip "only" when I have doubts, I think this is the correct way to proceed? I also thought code only answers were definitively not "low quality", but after failed review, I don't know anymore. There doesn't seem to be a definitive answer, so it's better to skip.

Comment: @Rodia Only having code isn't a reason to delete a post.  That doesn't mean you can't feel that it merits a downvote for being of low quality.  How is there, "not a definitive answer here".  There's a *very* definitive answer.  If you think an answer is low quality, you downvote it.  That's SE's mechanism for providing feedback on quality, and always has been.

Comment: @Rodia People here are just voicing their opinions and they are often wrong. To _beat the review queue_ you should follow what is being practiced by reviewers, not what is recommended on meta. For code only answers you should vote "delete" because such answers (in my experience) are deleted more often than not. The problem on SO is that to learn best practices you need access to VLQ which requires 2k rep.

Answer (score 72):

As someone who occasionally posts "try this {code}" answers, I would like to explain my reasoning.

In most of the languages I program in, code is surprisingly close to natural language. For example, let's say someone asked a question like

> How can I do something like `console.log`, but log it to the page instead of the console?

I might answer such a question with:

> Try this:
>
> ```
> var div = document.createElement('div');
> div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello, world!"));
> document.body.appendChild(div);
> ```

I would hope that it's fairly obvious that this code:

1. Creates a `<div>` element.
2. Appends a newly created text node with "Hello, world!" in it
3. Appends the div to the body

In fact, commenting this particular code or explaining the it seems... kind of redundant. I'm practically repeating myself.

***However***, this doesn't automatically mean that "try this {code}" answers are okay.

For example, if the {code} given is simply a copy-paste of the OP's code, but with a tiny adjustment, then the answer is poor quality because the code does not explain itself. In these cases, I usually comment with:

> While this does solve the problem, it's difficult to see why. Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of what you changed, why you changed it, and why it solves the problem.

Sometimes I'll downvote if it's particularly obscure, like just a single character difference, or if the edit made is only visible after scrolling horizontally, but overall, since it *does* answer the question, it's not really something I'd consider flagging for deletion.

Overall, it's really down to a case-by-case basis how I treat this kind of thing, and I believe my opinion on this is reasonable enough to be shared :)

Comment: When I first started learning JavaScript, I would have honestly been baffled by your "natural language code". Some people just don't get it at first and need things explained wherever possible. In my opinion there's no good reason not to include an explanation of the code. It really can make that difference in answer quality.

Comment: Your example answer should at least mention that the Document Object Model (DOM) interface is used. This is useful information for a JavaScript novice.

Comment: @RUJordan I've noticed that people tend to ask in comments if they need clarification on something. For example "awesome, it works, but why all the `document.` references?" at which point I would briefly explain DOM methods.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol For everyone who asks in comments, there must be several who didn't (including all the low-rep users who can't yet comment). And you shouldn't be answering just for the asker, you should try answer to all who find the question.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The reason you should explain it is that not everyone is going to comment.  Most of our 'users' are not registered - they are random people googling.

Comment: An answer should be self sufficient. One should not have to read the comment to understand the reasoning. If someone needs clarification, and ask for in the comment, this means that the answer needs to be edited to provide such clarification, and thus should have it in the first place.
However, I have to agree with @NiettheDarkAbsol that some answer do not ABSOLUTELY require clarification, but the "complexity" of the answer according to the poster should not be the deciding factor. Instead it should be the relative complexity regarding the OP's question and it's level of understanding.

Comment: @RUJordan when I was first learning English, I couldn't read.  Should we also include audio files for the illiterate, and only use the most 100 common nouns in English?  There are always, always going to be many people for which any given explanation is too complex for.  Saying that answers on a coding site should be understandable to someone who does not know how to code or read the language being asked about seems questionable (unless it is explicitly a question at that level).

Comment: Seeing as StackOverflow operates in english, that analogy is rather irrelevant, don't you think? There's a big difference between one who wants to learn, but isn't good, and one who just wants the code.

Comment: @RUJordan StackOverflow operates in English (for people who understand English), yes.  But it also operates in programming code, **for people who understand code**.  I would call the analogy spot on: a minimum level competency should be presumed, and failing to make that presumption makes a worse answer, not a better one.

Comment: I don't get this whole argument of clarifying code that explains itself. Why would we need to tell the OP that the methods are part of the DOM api? why is that relevant? Maybe the sample given in this answer is just too simple to demonstrate. In this particular case, i see absolutely no reason for an explanation. It's just too simple.

Comment: Agreed. When learning something new, a clear example is often sufficient rescue from drowning in difficult to read or unfamiliar documentation.

Comment: Granted, i never post answers without at least some kind of explanation (before someone searches my profile and proves me wrong), but that's just because I feel explanations always improve the answer. The lack of one doesn't make it a bad or low quality answer though.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the code in the example to be self-explanatory - it's far more confusing than using `document.write`.  Yes, `document.write` is bad, but the English explanation could at least be that simple - "Appends the text to the document via the DOM, contained in a `div`".

Comment: I often use the same reasoning, there are many occasions where it's clear the asker understands the fundamentals, and that the answer involves commonly used functions or methods for which no explanation is necessary beyond the code to get the job done.

Comment: I wonder if it would be helpful to have a collection of canonical links which could be conveniently attached to a post when the author thinks they are relevant [e.g. for the example above, link to a DOM tutorial and a reference for `document` references].  Having 50,000 answers also include a link to such references "normal size" within the text might clutter things up, but if shown compactly they wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 25):

Consider the [glass bottle vs. shoe](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925):

> "A client has asked me to build and install a custom shelving system.
>   I'm at the point where I need to nail it, but I'm not sure what to use
>   to pound the nails in. Should I use an old shoe or a glass bottle?
>
> How would you answer the question?

For the purposes of this discussion the answers may look something like this:

A) Try this: `hammer`

B) You may want to consider using a `hammer`, they can be found at your local hardware store and are specifically designed for driving nails. You simply place the tip of the nail in the desired location and then strike the head on the nail with the head of the hammer until the nail has reached the desired depth in your building materials. See the diagram below:
[image]

Now this may seem like a silly example, but which of the two answers really answers the question?

Given the question is "Should I use an old shoe or a glass bottle?" its probably fair to assume that the person asking the question wasn't aware of hammers, how they should be used, or where one might be found... So "Try this: `hammer`" may nudge them in the right direction, but it doesn't really provide a complete answer for someone who would ask this sort of question.

Now that that's out of the way...
Flagging answer A as VLQ seems completely reasonable to me, because in the current environment of SO answer B is very likely already posted and in many cases such questions will receive several versions of answer A in the first few seconds after being asked.

In cases where the above isn't true the person who provided answer A still has the option to improve their answer, which really should be the goal of all of this.

Some say that downvoting is the answer to this issue. I disagree. When the person who provided answer A sees a downvote on their answer, they are unlikely to see the reason for it unless it is followed by a comment. When it is followed by a comment they are left with the options of improving their answer or assuming that the downvoter is just a jerk who doesn't understand the brilliance of their answer and without the documented support of the community they are very likely to argue that their "Try this" answers are perfectly acceptable.

Institutionalizing a distaste for short incomplete answers seems like a much better option in the long run. Users who are trying to encourage better answers shouldn't be expected to go it alone. We need to give them the backing of the community and make it a common community norm that such answers are Very Low Quality.

Comment: But when you flag the post as VLQ it will meet none of the actionable items in the VLQ queue, because the post, while bad, is not so completely terrible as to merit deletion, so the queue will do nothing to it.  Your proposal is saying that we should waste a bunch of people's time and then do nothing.  That doesn't solve the problem at all.  When you see an answer that doesn't provide a sufficient explanation to the problem there are tools *specifically* designed to indicate that you feel the answer is not useful.  That tool is the downvote, as well as comments.

Comment: @Servy "actionable items" are now [only in the mind of meta regulars](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256364/839601). The only actionable thing for 30,000 LQ reviewers is common sense. It will probably take a while to learn how to live with new reality, but there seems to be no way back. You better think of how `Try this: hammer` would feel like for an average 2-3Ker reviewing it

Comment: @gnat So what are you saying?  That people are going to delete things that they shouldn't delete, using reasons that don't apply in the least, just because they don't like a post (despite the fact that the post meets no criteria for deletion) and as a result of this abuse of the queue we should start encouraging people to flag posts that don't meet any of the criteria for flagging so that people can abuse the queue to delete these posts that shouldn't be deleted?  Or am I mis-understanding you?  If that's what you want to try to encourage then you're just going to see the VLQ queue removed.

Comment: @Servy my point is, repeating meta rules that used to work so well in the past (when flags were mostly handled by diamond mods) will likely be useless. Nowadays, the way to impact how things work in the LQ queue is to learn about reviewers working in there, tune review audits, tweak how system raises flags based on quality filter, stuff like that

Comment: @gnat Yes, apparently we do have some work to do ensuring that reviewers in the queue are not improperly voting to delete answers that shouldn't be deleted, using whatever means we have to do so.  That doesn't mean that it's appropriate for this answer to suggest flagging posts that shouldn't be deleted and that have no reason at all to be in the queue.  Both users flagging posts like this and reviewers voting to delete them is wrong, and neither should be encouraged.

Comment: @Servy well, maybe yes... or maybe not. In the past, I could easily explain to self why strictness about flagging is justified. Back then, both deletion and undeletion typically involved diamond moderators, who are capable of handling quite a limited load. Nowadays this mostly seems to happen without their intervention (if I understand correctly, system only raises a flag for their information after author undeletes) so that reasoning I used to use doesn't apply anymore

Comment: @gnat So, what?  You're saying that because moderators aren't evaluating the flags it means that everyone should be encouraged to flag everything, regardless of whether or not the flag is correct, and that the reviewers should delete stuff that they very clearly shouldn't delete just because they can?  What are you trying to encourage here?  You realize that if the system does break down and start deleting tons of stuff that shouldn't be deleted it will be considered a failure, and we'll be forced to go back to the way things were before.

Comment: @Servy in the past, my criteria to decide whether something is worthy of deletion was if this justifies diamond mod intervention or not. This doesn't seem to be the case anymore. It's that simple

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
downvote
```

Comment: Yes, Downvoted -1

Comment: Done, another -1 for low-quality answers like this.

Comment: This solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, worked for me too!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's OK to offer attempted answers as long as you give more information than just a code block.  Explaining how you think it might help or what the code does is fine.  Answers that come this way almost always are born from questions that don't have enough detail to be sure on the answer.

Offering up some possible solutions, when one works you know why and can go back and edit the question to make it more useful for other SO users.  I see nothing wrong with this as long as it serves to improve the knowledge base.

Comment: I will make you a promise.  If I see you post an answer that doesn't work, I will downvote it (unless it's just because of a typo, in which case I will correct it).  The main reason for being able to comment under a question is so that you can ask whatever you need to know, in order to be able to post an answer that _does_ work.

Comment: In the jQuery tag, at the very least, the majority of "Try this" answers I see are on perfectly answerable questions, and the answers themselves tend to be incorrect. They also have a nasty habit of making very minor changes to code from the question itself, and expecting people to play spot the difference between the two.

Answer (score -2):

The language of this site is English, so natural language text should follow normal English idiom. "Try this" implies uncertainty: if you do this, it *might* work. If the poster is uncertain, then the question is unclear, or the poster is not knowledgeable. We don't want those kinds of questions and "answers".

If a colleague had a very difficulty problem, I might suggest they "try" something, and we together would iterate to a solution. That iterative approach would be appropriate for a conversational forum. But SO does not have that format. "Answer" posts should be for definitive "this will solve your problem" statements. "Try" posts should be comments, or not posted at all. It is right to flag code dumps with only a "Try this" introduction as VLQ. When I see them in the VLQ queue I mark that they should have been a comment.

Answer (score -7):

## Stack Overflow has no quality control mechanism. Period.

Learn to swallow it.

This site is not for the quality answers, this site is for collecting points and badges. With your silly demands you are just spoiling someone's game.

That silly voting measure suggested in accepted answer is just a palliative. An imaginary action. Most of meta residents participate in some imaginary Stack Overflow where everything goes as it should be - bad answers always downvoted, bad questions got closed, etc. For this imaginary SO their suggestions are all right. For the real one it's plain crap.

Say, if you follow this advise and vote down, this answer will be most likely upvoted back by an ignorant Samaritan, who can't read the code but feel compassion towards all the humbled and humiliated. Which will render whole action useless, leaving you with frustration. You can draw some attention to some particular question manually, posting as-though-abstract question on the matter at whole, linking particular answer as example. But it works only once - so, better save it for some extraordinary occasion. As of automated quality control, there is no mechanism at all.

And even flagging won't help. To understand the fallacy of the bad answer, the mod have to have decent knowledge in the particular area while the number of mods is so limited that you just can't have proper mod for the every particular problem. Not to mention that it require some *time* to get into problem - and mods are most short on time people in the world.

BTW, the worst part of these answers is not bare code without an explanation, but pure guesswork nature. Some ignorant rep-whore comes along, knows nothing of the basic language syntax, decides to fix some *proper* code, and posts it with notorious "try this" preface.

Comment: "Stack Overflow has no quality control mechanism. Period." - nonsense. That's what downvotes are for. And they seem to work pretty fine to regulate answers.

Comment: @JanDvorak as far as I understand, +15 from a single [desperate accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254860/839601 "what's this") suffices to counter rep loss of 7 (**seven**) answer downvotes. Not to mention that it saves question and answer from any kind of automated ["garbage collection"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773). Wonder how that would qualify as downvoting working "pretty fine"

Comment: @gnat Why does reputation matter though? It's not like people are going to take someone seriously if they have... 14 rep? (1 accept + one downvote) The roomba part does matter though, but I'm not sure if it's a problem. Poke Shog or someone to get the data for you.

Comment: @hichris123 you completely mistake reputation thing :)

Comment: @hichris123 can't you see, this is a way to encourage garbage posts. Step 1: pick unanswered question on its way to quick closure. Step 2: drop something (_anything_) in there, quick, before it's closed. Step 3: relax and wait until asker realizes that the only way for them to squeeze anything is +2 to accept. Step 4: profit. **Step 5: repeat**. The more garbage questions are posted, the more garbage you drop into answers, the more you profit. System encourages this and carefully preserves the garbage. And downvotes don't "work pretty fine" here, see my prior comment

Comment: The fact that this answer has 17 upvotes and 29 downvotes actually kind of proves its point.  If meta followed the same scoring rules as the main site, this answer would have gotten him over 100 rep (and have fewer downvotes).  Controversy gathers rep easily.  (Though on the other hand, this highly controversial answer is greyed out and on the bottom of the page - this site is not entirely without quality control.)

Comment: @YourCommonSense: [you cannot raise your voice against Stack Overflow!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257883/why-do-we-not-have-an-off-topic-flag-for-closing-as-off-topic/257906#257906) I am one of those upvoters here.

Comment: Well, I kind of expected something like this

Comment: @Brilliand: I do not think YCS cares about reputation and it is true  IMHO that this site is a reputation game for many, and traffic measure fo rthe owners.

Answer (score -17):

You're taking things **too verbatim**.

If someone is writing 'try this code', it doesn't mean he hadn't tested it! It can be a formulation for 'I recommend you that solution' as well!

Make simple test: does removing 'try this' part makes that question looking better? It's the code that constitutes the answer and not the honorific formulations around it!

If 'try this' is such a problem, you are free to edit it out, together with 'good morning sir', 'thank you' etc.

If it's about the size of the answer, not about the worning, use your common sence. If the problem is described on 5 pages, and the answer is one-liner, than it's for sure a low quality. But if the question is relatively precise and atomic, and the answer is a few lines of a code, than (if it's working) it **is** the answer. Such answers are often among [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tags, where often single-liner is what the OP needs.

Well, explanation is always appreciated, even in trivial cases, but lack thereof doesn't make the answer low quality per se. Well, it doesn't make them great either, but it's not the reason to remove or downvote them.

Comment: The problem with these answers is not that "try this" is wasting space, it's the lack of an explanation for the code.

Comment: Yeah you definitely misunderstood the issue here.