# Add a "code snippet only" reason on low quality queue

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, low-quality-posts

I have noticed a huge number of answers in the low quality review queue recently which have consisted of a line of code only with literally no text of perhaps an inane comment such as "Do this." with no explanation of what the code does or how it solves the issue or even how it can be used.

I would propose that we add a new reason for delete voting answers on the low quality queue stating that the answer contains only code with no supporting text.

Now this is admittedly a little subjective as there is nothing wrong with a long, well annotated and commented piece of code as an answer but an answer that is solely a short line of code where it is not obvious how or why it should be used does not seem a useful answer to me.

However I think it is far better than either flagging the posts as OK (where they do not help) or deleting them without reason (which does not tell the poster what was wrong.)

Thus I make this request and would very much like to hear other's opinions if there is any issue in my reasoning here.

Comment: @ArtjomB. That is a good point, but the poster can always make a new answer, and frankly the alternative is being closed without reason, then the OP does not even know how to fix it. Finally I would add that someone who had read the guidelines should know better anyway.

Comment: Answers as you described (few lines of code only) mainly come from low quality questions aswell anyway. Wouldn't it be better to deal directly with the questions ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet Sometimes, but my no means always, I have seen some good questions which attract these answers anyway, often along with a number of other better answers.

Comment: Mistyped: But that would mean that only 20k+ users can vote to undelete the answer if the user fixes the post.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Please see my first comment, it still largely applies to what you say here.

Comment: @gnat To The close-voter, I understand that this question is related, however I would argue that it is different as a feature request and not a discussion. However it is up for the community to decide if that is significant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, we should not have a stock reason for deleting answers that have code and a terse or missing explanation. In many cases, these are good answers, and we should not be encouraging the community to blindly delete them. Also, I don't know what "closing" has to do with this, since we only close questions, not answers.

This has been discussed before in ["Reviewing Low Quality Posts - Answers without explanation"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation), so I encourage reading the answers there for how many people recommend handling this. As I commented there, leaving a comment along the lines of

> "While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so."

can help in many cases by encouraging someone to expand upon their answer, but I don't believe code snippets that attempt to answer the question should be blindly deleted.

Comment: Sorry, the part about closing was just an error on my part, I had meant deletion. Still, that is a very good analysis of the situation, thank-you. Just to confirm then, is it best practise to leave a comment but ultimately flag the post as OK and move on?

Comment: @Vality - Yeah, commenting and moving on (or downvoting, if you think the answer is wrong or of a lower quality than others) is what I prefer. It educates the answerer as to what we'd prefer, and gives them a chance to improve. If we just delete the answer, they may never know what they did wrong and be perplexed as to why their answer was removed.