# Should I vote to delete poor answers in the VLQ?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I came across this answer in the low-quality queue:

[image: low-quality question]

I don't consider it a good answer. There's hardly any explanation of the code itself, the little explanation there is is in a code block when it shouldn't be, and the `catch (Exception e)` irks me out. I would definitely downvote it. However, it's still an answer, and doesn't really fit any of the standard deletion reasons.

I've came across several answers like these in the low-quality queue, and I'm unsure of the proper way to handle them.

Which is the proper option to pick for these type of answers?

- **Recommend deletion**: It is a poor answer with little explanation and problems in the code.
- **Looks OK**: It is an answer to the question, and isn't spam, a link only answer, etc.

Comment: If I hadn't taken a closer look, I would have flagged this answer as spam right after first coming across it in the mod queue, where answers are excerpted and any formatting is stripped. Just look at how that text is written. If that doesn't look like spam to you, I don't know what does.

Comment: You shouldn't recommend to delete answers _because "you don't like them"_, you should recommend to delete answers _because they are of low quality._

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I didn't word the title well, and this question was so old that I didn't bother to fix it until now. Anyway, I meant this question to be applicable to more than just code-only answers; stuff like one-liner answers too.

Answer (score 9):

It definitely is an answer, so you should not vote to delete it.

If you feel there are issues with it, commenting and/or downvoting are appropriate.

I base this on, among other things, moderator statements on similar questions:

[Reviewing Low Quality Posts - Answers without explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation/260424#260424)

> Save your delete votes for content that gives a link without explanation, or has absolutely no relation to the question being asked, or is otherwise unsavory content. – jmac

[Flag 'Try This: {code}' Answers as "Very Low Quality"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality?lq=1#comment30175_256359)

> VLQ basically means "unsalvageable." It doesn't apply to "try this {code}" answers. –  Robert Harvey

Comment: Even if there are 5+ other answers, and it adds nothing to them (only 4 others here, and I did not look any closer)? There's a point when more answers are worse, and merit pruning imho.

Comment: Could be grounds for moderator intervention (cleaning up excessive answers or protecting the question), but not grounds for deletion through the Low Quality review queue. I do believe in custom flagging new redundant answers on *old* questions, but the OP didn't indicate that was the case here.

Comment: Wait. What's the point of the "Recommend Deletion" button then? In addition to the aforementioned problem with the `catch`, that code will not compile as is, has a useless log print, gives no indication as to two variable types, and is riddled with grammar/spelling errors. Even without tracking down the question, I can pretty much guarantee that at least one of the other four answers has it right, if that is, in fact, what was asked. (Incidentally, if that was the question, it should've been closed as a dupe, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: Deletion is for things that aren't even attempts at answers: "thanks", "I'm having this problem too", requests for more info, updates from the OP (which should be edited into the question), etc. Not for incorrect answers.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification. I haven't done reviews, mainly 'cause I'm afraid I'd screw 'em up, as I would have this one.

Comment: I understand why moderators review as you describe. They have perfectly good reasons to be that cautious, as their decisions are unilateral, binding, hard to review and revert. But why pretend that you're wearing mod hat in LQ queue where _everything_ is purposely designed to be opposite

Answer (score 2):

The "its an answer" is irrelevant - the queue isn't the "not an answer review queue" - it is the **low quality** review queue (this is *different* than the criteria for the very low quality flag which has a much higher standard - that the VLQ flag feeds this queue doesn't mean that only VLQ is in the queue).  The queue text in /review reads:

> ### Low Quality Posts
>
> Identify, then improve or delete low-quality posts

Review it as such.  The fact that it was posted in the answer section of the text area doesn't preclude it from getting deleted.

The help text reads:

> This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
>
> - **Looks Good** if nothing is wrong with this answer
> - **Edit** if you can fix all the problems with this answer
> - **Recommend Deletion** to recommend that this answer be deleted
> - **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next item

As you note, there is something wrong with the question - its a poor answer with little explanation of the code or the problems.

You *could* edit it, ***if*** you can fix **all** the problems in the answer.  Note there word 'all' in there.  Editing the answer will kick it out of the queue even if all the problems with the answer aren't fixed.

This then leaves 'Recommend deletion' which is quite valid, especially if there are other answers in the question that do a better job of explaining the answer.

Vote and review in accordance with what you want Stack Overflow to become and what types of answers *you* want to find when looking at a question.