# Clarification for "this answer cannot be fixed" on link only answers (can I just delete link only answers?)

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

While processing the low quality answer queue, you are presented the following information about how to do so:

- **Looks OK** if nothing is wrong with this answer
- **Edit** if you can fix all the problems with this answer
- **Delete** if this answer cannot be fixed and should be removed
- **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next item

On the <kbd>**Delete**</kbd> option, what criteria should be applied to deciding if "this answer cannot be fixed"? Obviously, any edit by someone knowledgeable enough can change the answer into a correct one, but I am guessing that is not what is meant.

Is it common practice to summarily choose <kbd>**Delete**</kbd> for link only answers? The rationale is link only answers typically do not directly answer the question, but a change by anyone other than the author to add expanded information would be a radical change.

Comment: Related (and maybe dups): [Can we get an official stance on link-only answers in the LQP review queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270809/289086) and [Should I vote to delete low-quality answers that I don't like?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270002/289086)

Comment: Yes, I mash the delete button. Rarely are these link-only answers good enough that even the possibility of a radical edit could make them worth keeping.

Comment: Also related on MSE: [Reviewing low quality posts: when to delete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141851/reviewing-low-quality-posts-when-to-delete) with specific guidance for "if an answer is only a link" (though I will point out that I'm not in complete agreement with that - I am very pro activist reviewers when it comes to getting rid of crap and making the site reflect what you want it to be)

Comment: I'd like an option to convert some of the Link-Only answers to Comments. Some of them would make good comments because they contain nuggets of information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use the criteria in [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/1288) when processing low-quality flags and when reviewing.  The borderline between an answer and "not an answer" is this:

Answer (barely):

> You probably want a `FileOutputStream`

Not an answer:

> i think you should take The tutorial HERE! This will help you a lot

While the first post isn't *good*, at least it gives a scent to follow when the link goes dead. I click "Looks OK" on posts like that.  The second post is about as helpful as a bare URL. There's absolutely no useful information in the post itself, so I delete those.

Comment: Could we argue for a "looks terrible, but still qualifies as an answer" option..?