# How should I comment on code-only answers I encounter in the Low Quality Posts review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, comments, low-quality-posts

I've already looked at [Reviewing Low Quality Posts - Answers without explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation), but my question is a bit different - namely, I'm not asking if they should be deleted (I already know they shouldn't, I should vote "Looks OK"), but if and how to comment on them.

So upon encountering such an answer, should I add a comment telling the author that it's not good practice to post code-only answers?

Also, if it's good to comment on them, can you suggest a **good boilerplate comment** for pasting? Something along the lines of "Don't just post a code dump, are you a mute or something?", but in more polite terms?

Comment: Some of my highest voted posts are code-only.  Unsurprising on a programmer's site.  It does of course matter that it is the *right* code, is readable with appropriate comments where necessary and that it solves the OP's problem.  If you don't know whether the code is right or not then don't comment, ask your own question about it to learn more.  If you know it is wrong code then just DV.

Comment: How about something like "While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so."

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate. The [accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/1394393) on the question you link to *already addresses* this question. It very clearly states you should do this and provides some wording. The issue of commenting is even raised in that question.