# Two good answers complete each other, but which one should be rather accepted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I'm asking this question, because I cannot find *the proper explanation*.
I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326091/directions-api-total-distance-duration-with-waypoints) which had an answer before, but not fully covered and on demand of user I *"linked"* to another answer and completed it. Just linked to prevent copying someone's answer, because the way of answer is good, just not full. None of this answers is accepted now, but in case I have same situation, so my problem is solved, so question must have an accepted answer, but which to accept? This could be a little opinion-based, but I'm sure it must have more or less exact explanation.

Comment: It's entirely up to the user asking the quewstion to chose which answer to accept. Ideally, it would be the one that helped them the most.

Comment: I think so too, that's up to user, but still want to know rather it should answer to original question or on-demand answer, because it could mean that question was not too clear, for example.

Comment: And many times you'll find that the asker has no concept of "accept" being necesary, and the site cannot impose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which ever one helped you the most to resolve your issue.

Or comment on them both indicating you used parts of each answer and most likely one of them will edit to comprise of both.

This is then there for future use and a single accepted answer is in place to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think asking for using some code is a good practice. I agree. And seems *StackOverflow* delegated it to user completely. Thanks! :)