# Should answers always be explicit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33505338/824425) showed up in my flag queue.

To me, it seemed that OP misunderstands the sequence of operations between assignment and postincrement/-decrement, but that the answer addressed this so indirectly and even cryptically (the comma operator certainly won't help) that I doubt it's an answer rather than a comment.

As such, I marked it as "not an answer".

The answering user commented that they disagreed. The first time, I thought this wasn't constructive, flagged it as such, which was deemed "helpful" by moderators. The second time, it was as follows (emphasis theirs):

> This **does** answer the question. Answer must not always be **explicit**. Answers, especially if given in the form of extremely simplified and short code snippets, can also be **implicit**.

It's clear to me that I've made at least one mistake: flagging their defense. I'm not sure about my second mistake. At the very least, the template comment for "not an answer" isn't very fitting for this situation, and I should've been more specific, but I'm starting to think that there might not be a reason to flag this answer at all.

Is the answerer right? Are answers like these to be left alone in the review queue?

Comment: _"As such, I marked it as "not an answer"."_ It _is_ an answer. A _poor_ answer, but it is in fact an answer. "Not an Answer" is not for wrong or low quality answers, it's for posts that don't even resemble an answer.

Comment: NAA isn't for technical reasons. Consider downvoting.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was thinking more about didactic reasons (i.e. is the form of the answer clear enough to help the asker on their way?), but as I've learned now, those are also not NAA reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment is right. It is an answer.

Code only answers are fine, since they do indeed answer the question. One of the arguments that I hear a lot is that people may not know how to explain it (lack of fluency for English), and contribute through code. It's fine.

Remember:

- Even if answers are wrong, don't flag them. Downvote and move on, since reviewers don't need to consider the correctness/helpfulness of an answer.
- Even for code-only answers, they are not *very* low quality (e.g. link-only answers, requests for clarification, thank-you posts).  They are good enough to be considered an answer.

Comment: _"they are not low quality"_ Actually, it's very arguable, and often the case, that they are in fact low quality- But they are not _very_ low quality and therefore don't need a flag.

Comment: @Kendra Yep, that's what I meant. They're lower quality, but not low enough to warrant deletion.

Comment: I think OP is still in his right to flag as NAA, the answer although it may answer the question is so poor in quality, its like a link-only answer. So something that lacks explanation and reasoning its not an answer(at least for me) an answer doesn't have to be explicit **but** it shouldn't be implicit either

Comment: Code only answers are fine - I'll see if I can find a reference on that. But NAA flags are for links, thank you comments, requests for clarification and so on, because they don't objectively try to answer the question. Code only answers still try to answer the question, so they are allowed.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton How does it look like a link-only answer? The answer is entirely self-contained, and the answerer even actually put comments in the code as an explanation of what was happening. Could the answer be better? Yes. But it's answering the question and even has an explanation to it. (Of sorts.)

Comment: It's just code dumped onto a textbox, it's no use to future users without any explanation, just like a link-only answer would be @Kendra

Comment: How does a link help? Code at least provides an example. Links can die off. But code will be used to answer a question, regardless.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton I'd argue that a code-only is marginally useful for future visitors.  Just a lot less useful than code + explanation.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton Once again, it has an explanation of exactly what the code is doing- It's right there in the comments in the code. Either way, it's a self-contained answer. At most, it deserves a downvote and maybe a comment.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton The right action should be a downvote probably, not flagging as NAA.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton I understand where you come from, but code only answers aren't worthy enough for deletion, at least in comparison to the "I'm having this problem too!" sorts of comments.

Comment: [Some consensus on code-only answers and whether they warrant being called low quality](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/4293417).

Comment: @Kendra I understand what's going on, you understand whats going on we don't need and explanation, but have you thought about OP? You answer a question accordingly, in this case I truly believe an explanation was needed. You can see how the accepted answer has no block of code, yet it explains what it should be done and why it should be done.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton Not each author needs an explanation, some just need a working example, and some surrounding discussion. It objectively tries to answers the question (cross out NAA) and it's not low quality to warrant deletion. Get over it. If an answer doesn't answer to your standards, then write an answer of your own.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton Again, there _is_ an explanation in the comments of the code. Right there. In the answer itself. Even if it wasn't, this is easily remedied by commenting asking the answerer to add an explanation to his answer. There's no need to flag this, and no reason to. Downvote, optionally comment if you want to see it fixed, move on.

Comment: From the question: *Can someone have a look over my code and see what's causing this?* This is asking for an explanation, not just a working example @Zizouz212

Comment: And okay, let's agree to disagree and move on.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton Sounds good to me :D

Comment: Have a great one! see you soon in another post!