# First Posts Review Queue - Is this really a good audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, specific-answer

I recently failed [this code-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10210534) audit in the First Posts Review Queue.

As I understand from [previous meta posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260411/2415822), code-only answers do not warrant a NAA flag.  The answer is in fact an attempt at an answer.  Whether it is actually a useful answer will be determined by comments and up/downvotes.

Although I probably should have commented or clicked through to cheat the audit, I chose "No action needed" and failed the audit.  Should this answer stay as an audit?

Comment: I agree... It really shouldn't have been an audit. I wonder if helpful flags and stuff help push posts into audits (if that's the case, then I certainly imagine that some wrong flag got marked as helpful...)

Comment: This particular answer was deleted by the answerer, probably because of the comment that pointed out it did not in fact answer the question. It did not go through the LQP queue. I didn't know posts that were self-deleted could become audits.

Comment: Usual story, you did not get banned because you failed *that* audit.  You got the ban because you failed too many of them.  Everybody flubs an audit now and then, the system isn't perfect.  When you fail too many then you're not doing it right.  The machine is telling you to stop, look, listen.

Comment: @Tunaki I presume the two downvotes were a signal strong enough to be a candidate (through if I read the comment and/or question, I would probably downvote it too (even if I know next to nothing about asp.net))

Comment: @Tunaki: Not true. The post went through LQP, and was deleted by Community ♦ as a result of the review. http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9946960

Comment: @Matt Ha. Why doesn't the post appear to be deleted by Community ♦ then (for example, the post just above clearly says "deleted by Matt♦")?

Comment: @Tunaki: From my understanding, posts deleted via review will always show "deleted (date)", posts deleted by the post owner will show "deleted by owner (date)", and posts deleted by others (e.g. 20k's and moderators) will show "deleted by user1[, user2 etc.] (date)".

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the clarification, I guess I never noticed the "deleted by owner"!

Comment: @HansPassant, the ban is irrelevant to this particular question, so I have removed that information.  The discussion I want to start here is not about the ban, but about the audit.

Comment: Ugh.  The system is imperfect, are we going to have to have a meta discussion about *every* single quirky audit?  If you want to volunteer to hand-pick the audits instead of leaving it to a machine then SE might be interested in taking up your offer.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Never use "no action needed". This answer should have been downvoted.

Comment: @HansPassant: If we don't have a meta discussion about every single weird audit, the powers that be look at the stats and say "no one is really bothered by bad audits".

Answer (score 3):

I would say this audit is neither good nor bad, so I don't see the point in removing this specific audit (read: it isn't bad enough that it really should be removed).

This is "First Posts" queue and you are presented a code-only answer. It has been [established](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290233/1743880) [already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/1743880) that the appropriate actions in this case are a downvote, a comment or a VLQ flag (or maybe a combination of those three actions). But at the very least, a comment inviting the answerer to expand on the answer should be added. Note that this queue targets new users who might not have taken the tour. A typical comment could be (copied from the linked answer):

> While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

However, selecting "No Action Needed" is not appropriate. In this case, it turns out that you failed an audit, which might seem like a hard sentence; but you really shouldn't focus on that. Audits are what keeps the system running, some are just *meh*, like this one, but, again, I don't think it is also obviously bad.

You are right that a NAA flag [is not appropriate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) since, even if it's completely wrong (and I don't have the knowledge to judge), it *is* an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: VLQ flags are, imo, are kind of worthless in this case. If it goes into the Low Quality queue, what should reviewers do? Delete, or edit something that they are quite likely not going to understand? Then, we just see a "Looks OK" for the most part, and a declined flag. In most cases, why should I down vote either? Down votes are mostly a matter of opinion, judging the credibility and "workability" of an answer. If it's right, should I be *required* to down vote? I think not. Likely of interest is probably my answer here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309786/4293417

Comment: The [MSE post you link to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) is irrelevant. That's about link-only answers. This is about *code*-only answers that don't actually answer the question, at all. The OP didn't ask for code; the question was "why...?"

Comment: @Zizouz212 I didn't say you should take those 3 actions. I said, you _can_ downvote, you _can_ flag and you _can_ comment in this situation (read my answer again, I said "or" not "and"). You do the appropriate action (or a combination) if you deem it necessary. If you don't know want to downvote and don't want to flag, then leave a comment. You are required to do anything, you can skip also.

Comment: @ziz then you are left with the last option: a comment. Unfortunately SO doesn't have canned comments without deletion built in. Fortunately there is a userscript for that.

Comment: I don't see how a downvote would be more appropriate that "looks ok" in this case.  "Looks ok" to me means "leave it alone."  If others choose to vote up or down based on the usefulness of that post, then let them do so.  Why should I be penalized by just leaving a code-only answer alone?

Comment: Then what would I say in that comment that is also constructive, Tunaki? As  for you @JanDvorak, should I need a user script at all times in my browser, for "auto" comments? Again, what would I say in that comment?

Comment: @Zizouz212 The appropriate comment is linked in my post: "While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so".

Comment: @JAL No, "Looks OK" means it's a good answer. Not "I don't know", you should skip for that.

Comment: I just see that as discriminatory, against the reasons as for why we allow code-only answers. What if the code itself answers, what more would there be to add?

Comment: @Tunaki "looks ok" means "looks ok."  It does not mean "this is a spectacular answer."

Comment: @Tunaki "Looks OK" is really, there's no point in doing anything. I don't have the expertise in the field to warrant a vote, or I don't want to cast one for other reasons, the answer objectively tries to answer a question, and it's not low quality enough to be sent to a queue and warrant deletion, and there's nothing beneficial that I can add in a comment.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Then we agree here that it is not the case for this particular answer because there is something beneficial that you can add in a comment, i.e. more explanation in text.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I feel that no, it should not be an audit.

The base purpose of the audit concept is to make sure that reviewers pay attention to the post that they review, and to make sure that they take appropriate actions. Audits appear for a few reasons, including how much time you take (Yes, the time you take is recorded!), amongst other factors.

As for this particular audit, I'll simply reiterate my comment above:

> VLQ flags are, imo, are kind of worthless in this case. If it goes into the Low Quality queue, what should reviewers do? Delete, or edit something that they are quite likely not going to understand? Then, we just see a "Looks OK" for the most part, and a declined flag. In most cases, why should I down vote either? Down votes are mostly a matter of opinion, judging the credibility and "workability" of an answer. If it's right, should I be required to down vote? I think not. Likely of interest is probably my answer here: [Should answers always be explicit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309786/4293417)
>
> "Looks OK" is really, there's no point in doing anything. I don't have the expertise in the field to warrant a vote, or I don't want to cast one for other reasons, the answer objectively tries to answer a question, and it's not low quality enough to be sent to a queue and warrant deletion, and there's nothing beneficial that I can add in a comment.

Comment: Do you really think that this audit is so bad that it deserves to be outright removed? If you don't want to flag because you feel it's not necessary, and don't want to down-vote because you don't have the expertise in this field, a constructive comment inviting the answered to expand on the answer is the best action that could be made here.

Comment: @Tunaki But again, what would you flag as, and what actions do you expect to come out of the flag?

Comment: I didn't say you should flag but that you _could_ flag and that if you don't want to, at the very least you _should_ leave a comment.

Comment: The fact that there is no consensus on the actions to be taken is reason enough for this not to be an audit. Like I said, audits are done to make sure people are paying attention, not handle tricky out cases where other users are torn between doing things, and have no resources to help them react.

Comment: I think [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/1743880) is consensus enough, but yes, like I said in my answer, it is a _meh_ audit.