# Can we have a code only reason for deletion?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

A discussion for a possible feature request:

For code only answers can we please have a **code only** reason for deletion?

And if so, how do we word it?

[image]

Comment: Code only answers don't necessarily have to be deleted. They can often be improved by adding some extra text to the answer. I usually ask the poster to do so in a comment.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation

Comment: I've never voted to delete one, but when considering it, realised there was no suitable reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lacking an explanation isn't sufficient cause to delete an answer.

As long as the code attempts to answer the question, it's a valid answer. It may not be a particularly useful answer, but that's what *downvotes* are for, not delete votes. Feel free to downvote posts that are just dumps of code without an explanation, and encourage the user to explain what's going on as well.

Comment: I feel people have forgotten downvotes exist and just use flags as specialised downvotes.