# Review Suspension - Suspension in error?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

I reviewed Low-Quality posts on 11/08 and now I've been suspended until August next year because my judgement appeared to be "incorrect". These are the posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29553776
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29567934
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29569861
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29571906
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29572562
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29572629

I used Recommend Deletion on the posts because either:

- A code-only answer with no explanation.
- The answer doesn't directly answer the question.
- Should have been a comment not an answer.

These are very legitimate reasons to recommend deletion, and I can see that a few other users have also recommended deletion too, with some of the answers in question have now been deleted as per our recommendations.

I don't see any reason why I should be suspended let alone penalised for my correct judgement in helping to prune SO of low-quality answers. I believe my suspension should be lifted with immediate effect.

If for any reason my judgement was incorrect, please advise me what the correct choice should have been with a valid reason.

Comment: [Can we have a code only reason for deletion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312678/11682469), [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/11682469)

Comment: Relavant: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) and [Reviewing my Low Quality Posts Reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397302/reviewing-my-low-quality-posts-reviews)

Comment: The queue serves to validate the "Not an Answer" flag. If the flag doesn't apply, the post should not get deleted in the queue, see [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). As far as I can tell by the ones that are still around is that one needs an edit and the others are "Looks OK".

Comment: @user16320675 While moderators can choose a review ban length of up to 365 days, the typical progression, particularly for automatic review bans, starts with 2 days and doubles with each subsequent suspension, unless the user goes long enough between suspensions for that time to be reduced, or even to start over at 2 days. Your *assumption* that it happened "without warning" is unwarranted. Even your back-pedaling to "maybe after 3 warnings" is still just an assumption which doesn't accurately reflect the number of prior review bans which would *typically* result in this length of review ban.

Comment: @user16320675 Yes I've been suspended a few times before, but I think that was for failing the test reviews. This time it is for multiple post reviews, none of them were tests, and I wasn't warned about it at the point of submitting my review response. I reviewed on 11/08 and it says the suspension came into place on 23/08, therefore it seems like some moderator or someone has been involved...

Comment: @Studocwho Just to be clear, none of those reviews were audits. A moderator reviewed your history of reviews and directly issued the suspension for poor review behavior.

Comment: @Studocwho - Your previous review bans were your warnings.  You made mistakes while reviewing multiple times, were reviewed banned for those incorrect actions, you can’t claim you were not warned.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- **A code-only answer with no explanation.**

  Answers like this do not deserve to be deleted. Add a helpful comment asking them to improve the post and click "Looks ok"
- **The answer doesn't directly answer the question.**

  Do you really know that for certain? This queue isn't designed to judge this metric. Once you reach 20k+ you will be able to cast delete votes outside of the queue. For the moment, best to avoid judging quality of answers based on how well they answer they question. As long as it is an answer, do not recommend deletion. You can downvote instead.
- **Should have been a comment not an answer.**

  Yes, that is a good reason, but none of the examples you gave are comments. They all look like answers.

Your judgment was incorrect on these posts. They all looks like attempts to answer and they should not be deleted. The LQP (now LQA) review queue is designed to delete posts that can't be considered an answer at all. New questions, comments asking for clarifications, bumps, spam and similar things should be deleted. The rest should be improved or left alone.

However, it is really good that you came to Meta to understand your suspension. This is exactly what you should do when you are uncertain. I recommend you read other information on this topic:

[How do I use the Low-quality posts queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality)

[Reviewing low quality posts: when to delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141851/reviewing-low-quality-posts-when-to-delete)

[You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

[Reviewing my Low Quality Posts Reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397302/reviewing-my-low-quality-posts-reviews)

Comment: "Answers like this do not deserve to be deleted. Post a helpful comment asking them to improve the post and click "Looks ok"" Anyone has any post where this recommendation is helpful? I've seen plenty of cases where the only way those post are "improved"¹ is where there's a downvote. (¹ I say improved here in the way of deletion or total rewrite)

Comment: @Braiam - So downvote and move along, i would agree that, attempting to improve these low quality content yourself with a comment is a mind numbing exercise in the art of insanity. A downvote seems to be the only way to see any action by the author.

Comment: @SecurityHound well, I will downvote this one for lack of evidence. We can't suggest actions to people without a solid backing. The reason why code only answers get into the low quality review queue is precisely because the system identifies them as low quality.

Comment: @Braiam This has happened several times after I left a comment on an Answer. Without me downvoting it. I always remove my comment when the post has been improved. That the system does something doesn't mean the system is right. It's just not been asked to stop doing it.

Comment: @Braiam _"The reason why code only answers get into the low quality review queue is precisely because the system identifies them as low quality_". The system identifies them as potentially low quality. And even if they are, the sole purpose of the LQP queue is not deletion. Voting/commenting are also enabled. Saying that "this exists in the LQP, surely it means it must be deleted" makes no particular sense. Many of the users I see failing audits in this or other queues is because the reduce the queues to binary choices. Delete or not delete, that is not the only question.

Comment: @yivi "the sole purpose of the LQP queue is not deletion" [citation needed] the [low quality review queue has two maces](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253062/792066). It was designed to be a "fix this" queue with the two most powerful tools in our inventory: edit and deletion. The voting only was added because someone that shall not be named complained very loudly that people were deleting answers via the queue (which was kinda the point). A library of high quality Q&A shouldn't allow low quality A's to stay on the site. Allowing these post to stay is a aberration that should not be allowed

Comment: You do realize much of that answer is obsolete, right @Braiam? Voting, flagging and commenting were enabled for the queue.

Comment: @yivi that's why I call them aberration. The system worked correctly before, now it doesn't. The objective of "library of high quality Q&A" is lost when those changes were introduced.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the queue was originally designed for, nor why you think the changes were made, @Braiam. What matters is the tool that exists today. The other thing you are writing about, it's a FR: "make the LQP like this, because I think it's better that way". I may (or not) agree with that FR, but it's out of place here.

Comment: @yivi you know very well that such change would be unpopular. The community decided that it likes more their dogma than quality. I prefer people to still use the tool as it was originally designed, even if it allows more actions, because the other options makes no sense.

Comment: @Braiam - Features designed purpose can change over time

Comment: @Braiam: If answers were supposed to be deleted merely for being code-only, the system wouldn't add them to a review queue. It would delete them automatically (or prevent them from being posted in the first place).

Comment: @user000001 that's the thing, the system can't know with certainty that it's not just formatting. Also, the system up to a point rejected a post with a text/code ratio that was too low.