# New prefab comment / delete recommendation reason for LQP queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, low-quality-posts

I am proposing a new pre-selectable reason to "recommend deletion" that comes with a comment:

> Answers to non-trivial problems that contain code without any further explanation are unlikely to be of use for future visitors. Please add an explanation of your code to let your answer have lasting utility.

I'm running across these a lot. It gets a little annoying to have to comment every time.

Comment: AFAIK, current guidance is that a working wall of code doing what the asker wants is a legitimate answer, even though it deserves downvotes. (That is *not*, in any way, opposition to your idea.)

Comment: @Deduplicator Im arguing it shouldn't be. Just plain code helps almost nobody besides the OP (and even that only sometimes)

Comment: I entirely and fully agree on this one. A wall of code with no explanation encourages people to just copy and paste it into the software rather than trying to understand their issue and the solution, even if this is useful to the op it is not the right attitude for this site which is to help people to learn, not just programmers for unpaid hire.

Comment: I prefer the following "Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution." which I have in my [AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) addon ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill That would necessitate an extra button "recommend edit"

Comment: @Magisch Maybe ... I normally add the above as a comment, optionally downvote and then "Looks OK" if it appears to answer the question.

Comment: This would be an awkward user experience for the OP. You see the comment, and do what it says - "add an explanation". While you are editing, four more people reviews the post selecting the same option. Bam. The post you were told to edit is deleted and all your effort wasted.

Comment: But that isn't a reason for the post to be flagged, as such it is not a reason for the post to be in the queue, and so it should not be recommended for deletion in the queue. Please see: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/4639281). Flags are not a substitute for delete votes, there is a reason that we don't get delete votes until 20k. Also, keep in mind that accepted or upvoted answers go through a moderator queue even if they get unanimous votes in the queue, flags will most likely be declined on such answers.

Answer (score 14):

I really don't see a need to add this.  You can always use the [Auto Review Comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) userscript to leave your own comments.  I currently have one for answers that need more of an explanation:

> While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not understand why you have suggested this code or how it works.

This way you can customize what you want to say and you can add others without having to ask another feature request.

In addition **you should not use recommend delete on a code only answer** as it is an answer and not very low quality.  After I drop my comment I click looks okay.  You could skip if you do not like saying it looks okay but you should not recommend to delete.

Comment: People deleting these things from LQP irritates me to no end.

Comment: @Undo I feel you.  I think I have more looks okay or edits then I do rec delete.

Answer (score 6):

I entirely disagree with this feature-request.  [Code only answers aren't usually bad enough to warrant deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation).  In fact, [they should not be flagged as VLQ in the first place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256360/4320665).  Adding this option to the official list of canned review comments will lead to more people incorrectly deleting things that should only be downvoted.

When I come across these code-only answers in a VLQ review, I [leave a comment the way Nathan suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314182/4320665) and then I review the post as "**Looks OK**."  If it's particularly unintelligible code I also open the answer in a new tab to downvote it.

For more suggestions on how to process VLQ answers, [Undo's recommendations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) are a good reference.  Reviewers shouldn't be overly eager to delete stuff via the VLQ queue.  The community will handle the bad code-only answer via the roomba script by downvoting the bad code-only answers.

Comment: I'm glad someone brought up this point. Maybe you could mention [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/4639281) as well?

Comment: @TinyGiant that's an excellent resource.  I'll try to work it in.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also use looks okay after this.  Great answer.