# Custom actions/comments for review

Tags: discussion, review-queues

While [reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review) I often stumble over questions which require the same or very similar comment, e.g.

> "Welcome to SO, please have  look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..."

or

> "Please show some code that you have tried so far".

Hence, I wonder if it would be possible / applicable, to have a toolbar of custom comments (or actions) at hand for speeding up the reviewing process.

What do you guys think about that? Is something like that already planned?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been suggested before. Not sure where though.

Comment: there is userscript https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se . Also SOCVR uses a set of preformed [comments](http://comments.socvr.org/) using this userscript

Comment: Are you talking about when you are [reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review), or when you are just browsing questions?

Comment: I'm talking about reviewing.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314150/new-prefab-comment-delete-recommendation-reason-for-lqp-queue?rq=1