# Why do we place code-only answers in low-quality queue

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I did a search on Meta, and the consensus seems to be that code-only answers are often unfortunate but should not be deleted.

Some people recommend to downvote them. The review interface does not provide an easy option to downvote, and even if it did, I'd hesitate to downvote a question on technology I know litte about.

If we're not supposed to delete them, why do we place them in the review queue?

Edit: to clarify: I meant, more specifically, "why does automated algorithm places code-only answers in the queue?" I have to agree that we can't control what people flag :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET The automated algorithm for feeding the LQP queue is one of the main causes of this problem though, it's not just bad flagging.  These posts made up a decent percent of the items in the queue even before VLQ and NAA flags were directed into this queue.

Comment: To the *actual* question: Perhaps to avoid spammers getting away from the VLQ queue by just encapsulating their crap in code ticks?

Comment: Personally, I think they *should* belong in the low quality queue. I generally respond with a comment "Its often better to have a brief explanation than to have code only answers." The vast majority of these posts are posted quickly without much thought or tests, and don't do much to educate further readers.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams if a comment is the right answer, can we add that comment to the review inteface? I guess this is a separate Meta question :)

Comment: @Arkadiy It would be nice, especially since I get locked out if I hit a few of these in a row (which was actually the reason I came to meta this time). Another reason to discourage code-only answers is that they don't do anything to increase the searchability of a question. If the question is super simple and the user just doesn't know the keywords to search for, then this doesn't add the correct keyword association to the question-answer pair. If it is super easy to search for already, then you're rewarding help vampires and you should still be discoraged.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams LQP is there for posts that are just *terrible*, so terrible in fact that they need to be immediately cleansed with fire and deleted because they're just that obviously bad.  It's not there to deal with answers that are in fact answers, have a place, and shouldn't be deleted, but that might have problems to fix.  There are other tools in place for that.

Answer (score 14):

Simple: the system has *nothing* to go on when trying to decide on the quality of the post.

[Let's take this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868257/how-to-control-code-within-stored-procedure-in-sql-server/26868783#26868783):

> ```
> INSERT INTO STG
> SELECT ID,NULL,DATE FROM CUSTOMER
> ```

There are two ways the current checks could process this:

1. **Treating code blocks as prose,** this looks really bad - it's all in caps, punctuation and spacing are pretty wonky, and it's really short.
2. **Ignoring code blocks,** there's nothing left - so you get a rock-bottom quality score by default.

Either way, the results are bad - the system just isn't able to correctly determine when a block of code (in any language) looks good and when it doesn't. So we toss it in front of humans who presumably will have an easier time of this.

Note that the threshold for kicking these out of the queue is pretty low unless they *also* get flagged.

Comment: Granted, things would be a *little bit* easier if fans of certain languages didn't INSIST on pretending they're still writing code using 1950s TELETYPES.

Comment: Would you prefer Brain____ then? There's no letters in that language :D

Comment: I was just about to start submitting pictures of punchcards as answers, dammit...

Comment: This suggests that the current checks are too blunt. The system keeps dumping code-only answers into the low quality review queue. And while they may be bad answers, they are rarely ever bad enough to warrant deletion - [reference discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality?lq=1). I think it would be better if code blocks are indeed ignored, and if the post consists of nothing but code, then let it be.

Comment: Giving up is probably not a useful strategy here, @Lundin. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284563/reduce-try-this-answers-by-giving-a-helpful-message/284702#284702