# Is "very short answer" an answer or comment?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, answer-quality

In "Review|First Posts" today I came across this post link https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16346875.

[image: Answer]

This looks like a valid answer to me. And I am going to choose "No Action Needed". I am not an expert in this technology but know a little. Looking at the question, the contents of the answer `"set [newRowAtTop] = 'true'"` make me feel that the user is "attempting" to answer; it's a guess but not a wild guess. Just that they themself have not tried it before posting it as an answer.

On the other hand, this is very short and could be better in comments. N.B. The user do not have commenting rights; so they can't comment.

Another point is about "see what happens", which means the user is not sure if this will work. Generally, "try this" kind of text looks better in comments instead of in an answer.

So, what is the correct action here? The one I am about to take or flag this as Not An Answer?

Comment: Eh...the "see what happen" sounds like a guess more than a real answer but without that phrase, it would just be a poor answer. Advising the user to expand on how this solves the OP's problem would be reasonable.

Comment: I would downvote and ask the answerer to explain the solution..and move on. It looks like it falls in a grey area to me.

Comment: The length has nothing to do with it. Something very short could be a perfectly good answer, and something long could need to be a comment.

Comment: Typically I tend to leave comments on things like this telling the posters to expand upon their answer and explain why it should work.  The purpose of the overflow sites isn't simply for the poster to have their question answered, but rather for other readers who stumble across the answer at a  later time to be able to make sense of why an answer may/may not fit their particular scenario (and determine if a new question needs to be asked based on that).  Leaving a barebones answer with no explanation doesn't normally accomplish this.

Comment: Length is not always correlated to quality. One of my professors once said the best master thesis he has ever written was only ~20 pages long. Nevertheless an answer should carry some explanation on why the suggested solution solves the problem.

Comment: Somewhat related:   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318020/so-this-is-an-answer

Comment: No action needed? It needs at least an edit to fix the grammar/spelling.

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284563/reduce-try-this-answers-by-giving-a-helpful-message

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's an answer. A terrible answer, but an answer nonetheless. It's terrible not so much because of its length, but more because it's one of those unsubstantiated, "and see what happen [sic]" guess answers. Such answers run counter to the spirit of Stack Overflow Q&A — because we're not about guesses, we're about definitive answers — but they're not breaking any rules.

That said, deeming it a comment would be letting the author off easy. We don't want to encourage this sort of approach to questions at all, as it's not very productive.

Comment: Absolutely. This. Completely. (Although I'd caution against the "uneducated" assumption)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that wasn't the best word for it. How about "unsubstantiated"?

Comment: If this kind of answer is against the spirit of SO - and I would agree that it is - isn't it then a bit unfortunate that the [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page reads *"The answer [...] should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful [...]"* as it seems to be encouraging this kind of answer?

Comment: I guess the issue is you are implying the author doesn't know. I guess as you've changed "and see what happen" for "see if this works for you". The author could have meant "and see what happen" to be like "Voila! It works." Not defending the answer as the structure and formatting, or lack of, offends me.

Comment: @domdom: Quality and form are orthogonal. The passage you cite speaks only to the latter. Though I would tend to agree that it's a little too permissive of answers lacking any of the former...

Comment: You might also read it as an educational attempt which is a more positive spin on it. I'll give you the clue but see for yourself how it works out and perhaps learn a little along the way. The reasoning for posting the answer the way it is doesn't really matter; the answer is low quality, so it deserves to be downvoted.

Comment: @Gimby: The answer doesn't read as educational at all to me *because* it is just that low quality in its current form. That's the point I was trying to make. The answer is simply hard to take seriously.

Comment: Keep in mind that "See what happens" isn't always a "I don't have any idea of what I'm doing, try this". At least in my country, "try X and see what happens." sounds more like a challenge, as if the mentor/teacher already knows what is going to happen but wants the pupil to try by him/herself. It is a bad answer anyway for the quality standard that the Stack needs, but I wouldn't tackle that expression this harshly.

Answer (score 11):

It is an answer.

Comment: This answer's shortness underscores the very issue at hand.  If meta-meta-SO existed I'd upvote, but this answer isn't very helpful for this context.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like an answer to me. This would solve a problem. However, I find it quite incomplete. More details would be appreciated.

About "and see what happens", it might be a way to say "Tadaa! It works", to show that this was the solution. It might not necessarily be a simple guess.

This might become a clean answer with a little edit.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the question. If the question is of a simple nature, so that it can be answered by a single line, then a short answer is perfectly fine.

In this case the question is pretty detailed with code etc so it calls for an answer that addresses the examples in the question. In such cases, the posted answer is insufficient. And as mentioned, it is a bad answer because it contains "try this and see what happens", which suggests that the person posting the answer doesn't know these things themself.

Therefore I don't think anybody would object if you would cast a delete vote on this answer - it would have been better off as a comment. Preserving crap just for the sake of it isn't meaningful.

However, please note that the core purpose of very-low quality answer reviews is to filter out complete crap that doesn't even attempt to answer the question. In most review cases you don't need to know anything about the technology involved.

This answer, although poor, does attempt to answer the question. As a rule of thumb: if an answer attempts to answer the question, no matter how insufficiently or correctly, it shouldn't be deleted. Use down-votes instead.

So this isn't a black or white case, the answer could be preserved or could be deleted, and it wouldn't matter much. (Please note that the answer has been edited since this was posted, so it now of less poor quality than the original.)

Comment: `I don't think anybody would object if you would cast a delete vote on this answer`  I certainly would strenuously object.  Saying, "this answer to the question goes into less detail than I would like" is not a reason for deletion.  If you want to downvote it, by all means, downvote it, but deleting an answer to the question just because it doesn't go into as much depth as you'd like is completely inappropriate.

Comment: @Servy Nah. The answer, in the original form as shown in the question, is just crap of very little value to anyone. It is highly doubtful if it even answered the question. Preserving crap just for the sake of it fills no purpose. Mankind does not benefit from us preserving every single bit of crap on SO and putting it on pedestal for future generations...

Comment: So you go around deleting answers without even knowing if they're correct or not, just under the assumption that they're *probably* incorrect (not that an answer being incorrect is a reason to delete it either).  Other readers appear to believe that it's the correct answer to the question (ones who are subject matter experts, rather than people who have no idea if it's correct and just assume that it's not with no basis for that assumption).  Should I go around voting to delete all of your answers just on a baseless assumption that they're probably wrong?

Comment: The answer appears to be of little value to *you*, because you aren't looking for a solution to that problem, but for anyone that has that problem, and is looking for a solution, it may well be *very* valuable to them.  If you want to assert that an answer is crap, then you need to have a basis for it other than your uninformed assumption that it's probably wrong.

Comment: @Servy Please do that and see what happen.

Comment: So you're saying that it's okay for you to do, but not for anyone else to do?   You're saying that now you suddenly realize that it actually *is* wrong to vote to delete an answer with no basis whatsoever for deleting it?  I'm glad that you've come to this realization all of a sudden, and I look forward to seeing your edited meta question that takes this into account rather than advocating deleting answers for no reason at all.

Comment: @Servy Hint: my comment answered you with more or less the exact wording of the answer that you insist we must preserve. You then replied with several questions asking for clarification since you didn't understand what my nonsense answer was even supposed to mean. Instead you made up a lot of things you _thought_ I said or wished I said. Thus my answer to you was completely awful and not a meaningful way of communication between humans. Point proven.

Comment: The implication of your comment was clear.  You were asserting that the behavior wasn't appropriate.  My questions were rhetorical, not clarifying questions, specifically pointing out the absurdity of your statement, as should have been made clear by the last sentence not being a question.  The answer you want to delete does not *imply* what the answer should be, it *explicitly states* the answer, with no assumptions necessary.  The criticism of it is that it's terse, not that it implies the answer instead of stating it.  So no, your point isn't proven.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of an answer.
A little intuitive,
wanting the question OP to do some actions step by step and see how it goes from there.
Most of the times, it won't be a good answer though.