# Answers phrased as a question

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

When reviewing the close queue, I'm frequently seeing people claiming "this is not an answer" on potential solutions phrased as a question. Sample:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52975639/119549

Like if someone says:

> Does it work if you add this line of code?

...it really means the same thing as:

> You should add this line of code.

...only phrased in a way that some people hold conversations when trying to help them solve a problem. Should we really close things of the former pattern as "not an answer" and ask them to post as a new question when it's obviously not them actually asking a question?

**Update**:

I think the "duplicate" question does cover the same topic, but it doesn't have sufficient clarification for my specific case. I think people are being literal and say "a question is not an answer, therefore this is not an answer." Given how frequently this happens, I think it'd be good to communicate this specific case.

**Update 2**:

OK, the close reason I think is wrong, but [Should we avoid rhetorical questions in answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers) is definitely a real dupe.

Comment: see also: [Should we avoid rhetorical questions in answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300987/839601)

Comment: Also related: [Is "very short answer" an answer or comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350305/7795130)

Answer (score 11):

The NAA flag isn't appropriate for those kind of answers anyways, since there's an attempt to answer the question.

That the introductory phrase is formulated as a question doesn't matter.

Comment: Agree. But it's still not a good answer and would be better as a comment. It completely fails to explain why these two lines would make a difference so it is unclear if this is just random guessing or a fact based answer.

Comment: @BDL Even then NAA is wrong, and VLQ would be the appropriate flag. Or at least editing and reformulate would be the right path of action.

Comment: @BDL Bad answers don't belong in comments. Bad answers need to be curated by downvotes, something you can't do to a comment.