# How strict is the review suspension system and can you object for this ban?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I've received a second ban in a row for the review queue. Now since it has happened for the second time, I'm starting to question whether I review the questions so wrongly or that the system is just very strict.

The review that got me banned was this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/25128047

I wonder how tight the review ban system is and at which point you are getting banned. The first time it happened to me was last week, and I also couldnt quite fathom why it happened so fast.

Comment: Not the best choice for an audit, IMHO!

Comment: Posts to use for review audits are selected algorithmically using a fairly primitive algorithm, see [How Are Review Audit Posts Selected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189009).  I agree that's a bad post to use for an audit review, in fact it's questionable whether it should have been deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree that the audit you failed was incorrect. That answer should not have been deleted. (Now that it's been undeleted, it is no longer eligible to be chosen as an audit,  so no one else will be tripped up on this one in the future. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.)

That said, your [recent review history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346367/flame?tab=activity&sort=reviews) is still troubling to me in a number of ways. I didn't go through *every* review that you've done recently, but I did go through the first page (which consisted mostly of "Late Answers" and "First Posts" reviews) and spot-checked the second page.

When confronted with answers, you've generally made the right decision that they *are*, in fact, answers, and should not be deleted. However, almost all of them have been of rather low quality and desperately in need of editing. You should have made edits to improve these answers.

When confronted with questions, many of them have also been in need of editing. Some of them needed edits to *add information*, edits that can only be done by the asker. In this case, you need to recommend that these questions be closed.

I don't think you are doing any *major harm* with your reviews, but I also don't think you're leveraging the opportunity to improve the site, either. Therefore, on balance, I've decided not to lift your current review suspension.

Please use the time to review our guidance on how to review, especially:

- [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)
- [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue)

If you have questions about how you should have handled certain reviews differently, please feel free to ask about those here on Meta.

Comment: Hm I've clicked through the first link you gave on my profile but it's a bit hard to get an overview on what I did wrong or right. Im also confused how I've managed to pass hundreds of reviews but only got penalties in the last week or so. I think you're right though that its worthwhile to edit questions more often than I do. Guess ill wait 2 weeks...

Comment: I agree with the most things you all are saying. The OP audit wasn't the best, cause the audited post was a NAA. Besides, When I see the answer having 2 or 3 short sentences I mostly flag them as NAA. Having a question answered by so small number of words looks like the question itself is pretty bad. For me such answers should appear as comment and question to be closed. I'm not sure if this is right approach, so if there's a discussion about it somewhere here, please provide some link (I couldn't find it).

Comment: @itwasntme *"Having a question answered by so small number of words looks like the question itself is pretty bad."* - Questions and answers should be reviewed independently of one another, a bad answer doesn't mean a question is bad, just like a exceptional answer doesn't even mean a question is good. The audited post was *not* NAA, it is a valid attempt to answer the question, whether it is right or wrong doesn't make it not an answer, see here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350305/ and also perhaps here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/

Comment: @NickA thanks. I'm not saying that there is a strict relation with a answer containing small number of words (aka "bad answer") and a bad question and otherwise, the sentence you quote is just my personal feeling (but not always). While reading the Q you've provided I came across https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318020/so-this-is-an-answer (and some others, with the comments ofc). For me it seems we should treat just an attempt to answer as an real answer, even if it'd be smth like "try xxx instead yyy". Isn't the "I don't know" also an attempt to answer?-prbbly for those the downvote.

Comment: @itwasntme Take a look at the [NAA FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/). You'll find *"Don't use this when: The user posts a partial answer/The answer makes an attempt to answer the question, even if it is wrong or inaccurate or you disagree with it"* (your first example falls under these 2), you'll also find *"You may use this flag when: obviously dishonest answers to the question. .... **But sometimes they are just a well-intentioned, but bad joke**"* (your second example). Ultimately, use some common sense.

Comment: You explained what they the OP wrong and they'll either improve or fail again. IMHO you should've lifted the ban as it was issued for a wrong reason, so the OP may feel it as unfair (that's really just my opinion, not to be taken too seriously).

Comment: @maaartinus the fact that the final nail in the review ban was a poor audit doesn't excuse the fact that there are other poor reviews as mentioned in the answer

Comment: @NickA sadly I cant tell which other reviews were regarded as poor. However I'm not sure if a 2 week ban benefits anyone, because I've now read everything in this post and I dont need 2 weeks to process that information.

Comment: @Flame Perhaps if you asked Cody very nicely he'll give you examples, no promises though

Comment: I pretty much summarized in the answer why I think all of your most recent reviews (the ones listed on the first page of results) were problematic. For answers, you didn't edit enough, leaving low quality posts visible on the site with no attention. For questions, you also didn't edit enough, nor did you recommend closure frequently enough. As @Nick said, even if the audit was incorrect, we do treat this as "the final nail" in the coffin. The two-week period will give you time to review the FAQ guides that I linked in my answer as well.