# It seems I reached the ban limit

Tags: discussion, triage, review-suspension

I got suspended from the review queue again. This has happened a few times in the past now and the ban duration keeps stacking up. My current ban will be lifted on June 4th (60ish days from now).

I am willing to spend my time improving this website but it feels like I have reached the point where a single error puts me back in the banned queue, for reasons that I don't think are convincing.

#### Which review wasn't helpful?

Apparently the flag that I put for https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25744353 was incorrect.

The question was in my opinion valid, only it could've used some code formatting. The question could be interpreted as "I want this community package installed, even though it is not supported for another dependency I use".

So I put `Requires Editing`. Apparently other users disagreed and voted `Unsalvagable` (2x) and `Looks OK` (1x).

So based on these 4 votes, I can safely conclude that consensus hasn't been reached at all. The only difference is that I basically voted "needs work" instead of "fail" or "pass", so it pushed some work onto the queue for someone else.

#### Are there any other instances where I failed to review correctly?

Probably. I can't seem to find an interface where a sum up of my reviews is shown with accept/decline rates though. There's only https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history available which doesn't show me useful feedback at a glance. So based on this data I'm assuming I got banned for 1 error.

---

This seems very harsh to me. While clicking through https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1346367 (this page isn't publicly accessible but it shows all flags for my account), I found some other flags that apparently were **declined** but were fair to report nonetheless.

Based on this page I can conclude that I've created a total of **223** flags, of which **5** were declined, **37** were disputed, and **51** were aged away. I don't think that's a bad average.

I'm going to review all **Declined flags (5x)** quickly and elaborate why they shouldn't incur a penalty:

- Post Flags

  - Very Low Quality: [Dynamically plot last 100 entries of column formatted data using Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964283/dynamically-plot-last-100-entries-of-column-formatted-data-using-gnuplot)

    - Disputable. User mentions affiliation with a company quite prominently and mentions a product. Question turned out to be closed as well.
  - Very Low Quality: [How to Scraping with array in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887696/how-to-scraping-with-array-in-laravel)

    - It might not be "Very" low quality, but based on the answer this one does not seem to be useful to anyone else other than the question owner.
- Spam Flags

  - Spam: [SDHC CARD - Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966600/sdhc-card-initialization)

    - Disputable. I saw links to many different URLs so I assumed linkbuilding activities or other SEO. In addition it was a new user. If not Spam, it might just as well be "Needs more Focus" based on the huge blocks of code.
- Rude/abusive Flags

  - Rude or abusive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980440/cant-to-create-sql-query

    - I cant see the question anymore since it has been removed, so I cant see why I reported this. It shows -4 votes however.
  - Rude or abusive: [Array using user input and for loop gets NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698483/array-using-user-input-and-for-loop)

    - Disputable. User seems to boldly ask in capital letters what the issue is with his code.

Now the flags aren't possibly the only measure that's taken into account when banning users from the review queue. I'm not sure what else is checked.

---

I felt I needed to elaborate on my experience, and I am wondering if Stack Overflow isn't missing out on reviewers if the ban system is so tight.

Comment: You do understand that "requires editing", indicates the question needs to be improved by somebody other than the author, is that the case with the question your asking about?  The reason the bans are so long, are so you take notice of the fact, you are selecting the incorrect choice in that particular review queue.  The fact you already reached 60 days, means, a moderators previous attempts to highlight your incorrect choices were not noticed.

Comment: "Very Low Quality" should only be used for question which are downright gibberish. I don't see spam in the question marked as spam. The rude flag on the non-deleted question is also wrong: The question text was not rude towards anybody.

Comment: For the review you [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25744353), what would you edit about it to salvage the question, or what would you expect someone like myself to do when we are asked to edit it in the [help and improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) review queue?

Comment: @Larnu: Given that Flame reviewed the first revision of the question (which has been closed) and some random user already edited it into shape (and got it reopened), the H&I queue should have [applied exactly that edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60964942/revisions). Requires edit is really often missused. But this time it imho wasn't.

Comment: @BDL - The [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60964942/1) the author saw, was before the question was improved, in this case "requires editing" would have been the incorrect choice.  This is supported by the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60964942/timeline).  While the question was ultimately improved by somebody, in the case of the triage queue, the incorrect decision was made (IMO).

Comment: Even when reviewing the second revision, I'd still go with "Requires Editing" because the syntax highlighting on the second codeblock should be removed and there is a wrong capitalized Install in the last sentence.

Comment: @SecurityHound: How can you say that "Requires Editing" was the wrong choice when afterwards someone else than op edited the question into shape?? This is exactly the case which requires editing is for: questions that can be fixed by someone else than op.

Comment: @BDL - I made that decision based on the fact the current revision looks nothing like the original revision.  If it was the correct decision then I can't explain the review ban.

Comment: @SecurityHound: They are probably banned because the mods ban everyone who chooses "Requires Editing" on a question that is closed afterwards. They don't automatically take away the ban when the post get's reopened and it turns out the the review was correct.

Comment: @BDL - So a blanket policy?  That seems like a policy that would result in more work instead of less.

Comment: @SecurityHound: No, I don't suggest any change to the current mechanism. The ban should just be lifted now. And I suggest not to tell the asker here that there ban is deserved/correct. I also don't understand why this post is downvoted given that op definitely has a valid point.

Comment: @yivi I guess it could be a duplicate depending on how you interpret the author's intention (does he want to circumvent this issue or simply want to know why?). Most importantly I dont want this thread to be about this specific review. As you can read in the bottom half I consider my other declined reviews to be gray-area to say the least. Not to mention the amount of total reviews compared to the handful of errors I made shouldn't result in months of bans.

Comment: @Flame - You had moderator flags declined, which have nothing to do with your ability to do additional triage reviews, and you make no mention of being unable to raise additional moderator flags.  *You choose the incorrect decision when you review that question in the queue.*

Comment: @SecurityHound I guess I mixed up incorrect flags and incorrect reviews, but I cant tell if it was a combination of these things that got me banned. It sure sounds odd that a single wrong review would immediately initiate the ban again.

Comment: @Flame - Your moderator flags being decline has nothing to do with your review ban.  Your ability to raise a flag is separate from your ability to perform triage reviews

Comment: Ban was not just for this particular question you linked. See also https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25744229, https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25746456, https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25472655, etc.

Comment: @SamuelLiew why is that 2nd one off-topic? The other 2 are indeed erronous reviews. Also is there an interface that shows this list or do you have to click through all reviews manually?

Comment: [On this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25746456) there is an error screenshot and nothing else. How would anyone be able to offer an answer to that? Needs to be closed until the asker adds the necessary details to their question (if they ever do).

Comment: @yivi thats not the definition of off-topic. It should be flagged "Needs details or clarity" then.

Comment: @Flame - A question that only contains an error, should be closed, nobody should be attempting to salvage it except the author.  Your picking the incorrect choice on some truly low quality questions.  Half of these reviews are no longer available due to the questions being deleted (I believe that to be the case)

Comment: Flame, three things, and I'm done here: The most important: it's better that a question is closed for the wrong reason that it remains open; you were suspended because you chose on "requires editing" on a question that needed closing, **that** should be your focus. Second one: topicality on the site is not only subject matter dependant, but _form_ dependant. For example, opinion based questions are "off-topic", even if the subject matter is programming.

Comment: Third and last, a recent post-notice redesign sadly hides information from users. That post was closed with [this reason](https://imgur.com/a/PaDUGip), which is entirely appropriate. But that is hidden from users below 3k, I'm not entirely sure why. With this I'm off. Good luck in the future!

Comment: @Luuklag it seems to be the situation I experienced. I did not read the whole thread though because there is very very much information :p. I see a lot of sensible suggestions in the thread though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Apparently the flag that I put for https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25744353 was incorrect.
>
> The question was in my opinion valid, only it could've used some code formatting. The question could be interpreted as "I want this community package installed, even though it is not supported for another dependency I use".

That question should not have been reopened, even when edited. It is a dupe best, of one of the many, many, many questions dealing with *"I'm trying to install a package and composer is telling me my requirements can't be fulfilled"*. There are infinite combinations of incompatible packages, and we do not need a question for each incompatible combination.

And without a `composer.json` file, it's basically incomplete.

"Requires editing" is a sadly misleading label. The option is only good useful when the question is otherwise fine, but can be can use some fine polishing by third parties. Using it for a very poor question that should be closed is the wrong choice.

You were suspended so you could be made aware of this, not to punish you.

Logically, you participate in the review queues because you want to help and contribute. If your actions are not helpful, it follows you are the most interested in learning how to review better, so that your contributions are actually helpful and not detrimental.

The suspension is meant to give you the opportunity to do exactly that.

The fact that it is this long means that there is very likely history of reviewing incorrectly, and also likely recent suspensions (that maybe you missed entirely, since the current system is flawed not only does not notify users when they are review-suspended, but actually makes it hard for the suspended users to find out).

When you are suspended less than 30 days after your last suspension ends, usually the next suspension will double the duration of the last. Nevertheless, moderators can decide to issue suspensions at their discretion according to the severity and frequency of the user's mishaps on review.

---

You are mixing up "declined flags" and "review suspensions". Those are different things, and generally unrelated. Declined flags may trigger an automatic or manual "flag suspension", and during a time you wouldn't be able to raise additional flags. The idea is similar than a review suspension: by raising incorrect flags you  are taking time from the moderator team to investigate things that do not need to be investigated. Ideally, the flag ban will make you take a step back and research on which flags are appropriate in each case.

You do not mention you are flag banned, so I assume you are not; and are simply conflating unrelated matters.

Comment: A ban is to punish you, a warning is to make you 'aware'. I get a 60 day ban for 1 wrong review on a streak of 40-60 reviews. This duration is outrageous and completely useless as well. The next time I will get a 120 day ban again for another arbitrary problem. I am not flag banned but to be honest that makes it even worse since it means bans are being given for single instances of errors, among large quantities of fine reviews. The sole fact that this question got all 3 different categories in 4 reviews says enough about the ambiguity of the situation.

Comment: No, a suspension is not punishment. It really can't be punishment, since the only thing it's doing is preventing you (temporarily) from doing work for free. The problem is not arbitrary, it's very clear cut. If you want to help, better learn how to help effectively, don't you think? This review was not helpful.

Comment: The next time will be 120 days long only if it's less than 30 days after this suspension ends. Instead of anticipating the next suspension, learn how to work on the review queues, and you won't be suspended at all. It's entirely possible.

Comment: It's not a very clear cut problem. The question was badly formatted. At the same time I'm told to use flags sparingly to avoid raising incorrect flags. Which option do I take? You would almost become anxious to review a question because of this. Wouldn't both lead to the same result in the long run if I am allowed to make 1 error? I bet someone else would've stumbled over another review I did and I would still get a 60 day ban for 1 issue out of many.

Comment: It's a extremely clear cut problem. That question could not be salvaged by third parties editing it. Requires editing was the wrong choice. You are asked to use flags sparingly, but only certain flags. I'm afraid that's yet another problem with naming and labels on the site. The problematic flags are those that require a moderator intervention: spam, rude, very low quality. Flagging for closure, if a question merits closure, it's never problematic.

Comment: When suspensions are dealt manually "for a single mistake", most of the time can be lifted early **if the suer understands that they reviewed incorrectly**. Your suspension is much longer **because there is more than a _single mistake_**  in your review history. Again, I'm sure that a mod could lift the suspension early anyway, but I would assume they would want to make sure you understand how you are supposed to review going forward. If you persist in saying "this was a reasonable choice", well, I personally don't see the point in a mod lifting the suspension.

Comment: And I hope you realize I'm just trying to help you here. I get that you want to contribute, so all this is just for your benefit. It's up to you taking or rejecting the advice.

Comment: Why didnt the other 3 reviewers vote for a close? Its also the second time you mention 'misleading labels' which points me to the fact that the review system is difficult to deal with.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of misleading labels. The UI sucks. And moderators can't change those. But they can issue suspensions so users can be made aware of the rules. So they use those. If users learn the rules and want to continue contributing, awesome. We all win then. Those three users got it wrong as well. Many users get it wrong all the time. It happens. There are also many users getting it right. Try to focus on those.

Comment: I would also like to mention this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393078/how-strict-is-the-review-suspension-system-and-can-you-object-for-this-ban which is a previous appeal for another review. How high is the bar for reviewing? I'm failing to see how a couple of reviews among hundreds can cause so many bans for me. Its a hard pill to swallow to know that this is going to happen again in the future and that there is nothing about it that I can do to prevent this, except give my life to SO meta and read every single Q/A there is.

Comment: @Flame - Just because other users also picked the wrong choice does not justify your incorrect choice.  I would like to point users actually did raise a flag to close the question.  **Out of 4 users who reviewed that question only two of those users selected the correct choice.**

Comment: @SecurityHound Just to be clear we're talking about the first link in the original post. That question is not closed at the moment. What happened to the close-flags that were raised?

Comment: @Flame - Yes;  I am talking about the only review that you have asked about.  The rest of your links were flags.  The question was closed, it was then reopened due to the appropriate flags being raised, it's in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60964942/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries).  However, it seems like the question perhaps should have never been reopened, but that should be a separate debate.  Your review  didn't consider the improved version of the question, you reviewed the original revision of the question, before any edits were made.

Comment: To be clear, a large part of the reason that temp bans are used instead of warnings to make you aware is that it's the _only tool that moderators have at their disposal_, and even then it doesn't work particularly well because it's hard to tell you're banned.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving