# Answers that say "try this" or similar in addition to description of solution

Tags: discussion

I seem to be noticing a lot of answers now say "try this" or "you could try this" or something similar next to code example after some explanation text.

I'm probably being pedantic but these answers annoy me because the "try this" prefix seems to be a disclaimer to say "well it may or may not work I don't know", or "I'm haven't tested this", or "this is a just a guess but hey why not".

I'd rather an answer was an actual answer from a position of confidence rather than  disclaiming responsibility for it by saying "You could try".

Note: this is not a duplicate of [Reduce "try this" answers by giving a helpful message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284563/reduce-try-this-answers-by-giving-a-helpful-message) - that duplicate was focused on answers that are primarily code blocks.  My objection is to "try this" in general.  I think SO should look for "try this" in the text and ask that people use different words such as "this is not tested", or "I am guessing here", or perhaps if they are from a cultural background where people prefer to give suggestions rather than definitive factual answers, then a way could be found to explain that it is not appropriate to say "try this" because it reduces the quality of the answer by making it vague and uncertain. There are definitely other discussions on this topic as shown in the comments but some of them are years old, indicating that the issue isn't addressed.  It must be a fairly easy one to address in code because "try this" is such a straightforward piece of text to identify.

Comment: Related meta question: [Is “try this” bad practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice)

Comment: You claim that this is an easy problem to fix, and yet haven't actually made any proposal to actually fix it, and have just done what all the people before you have done, which you've already seen, and said that you don't like it and left it at that.  If you can think of a good solution, then *propose one* (after ensuring it hasn't been proposed before, or that your proposal adds something new).

Comment: The phrase all by itself doesn't inspire much certainty indeed. But depending on context ("If these two options fail, then try this to foo the bar: …") it can easily be just decorative. - Unlike the more prevalant Try-this-code-dumps (which as of late are mostly just unattributed copy'n'pastes)

Comment: After 16.5 million questions with near certainty that a duplicate for most any new question exists, Q+A has devolved to a point where a questioner now gives as little info as possible to avoid getting his question closed.  Answerers have to guess at the correct answer with little to go by, they acknowledge they do so in their answer.  Dup-votes and edits to remove "try this" can still occur later when the guess turned out to be correct.

Comment: For an annoyed person, you don't downvote much. ;-)

Comment: @Don'tPanic I really disagree with downvoting unless justified. IMO downvotes should cost 1 reputation point. When negativity costs nothing, hey - what a surprise - lots of negativity.

Comment: Downvotes on answers do cost reputation, actually. I absolutely agree with you about not downvoting unless you feel it's justified. It's just that, in my opinion, if it's a guess instead of a real answer, downvoting _is_ justified.

Comment: @Don'tPanic oh I did not know that downvotes cost reputation.  Maybe it should be more obvious then it might be more effective as a mechanism to minimise drive by downvoting.

Comment: the "try this" one i dispose are the ones which is just the code dump and not explaining what they do to fix the problem thus (in my opinion) are totally useless to anyone without the same code from the question. those ones i just downvote as not useful (as per the hover text)

Comment: What? Do you think "I am guessing here" is better than "Try this"!? NO.

Comment: I disagree this is a duplicate (at least of given target). The target question is about low quality dumps of code with "try this" as the only explanation. This question is about putting "try this" in answer as an indicator that answerer does not believe in his own question quality.

Comment: @HansPassant You're assuming most people asking questions care more about not having their question closed as a duplicate, rather than simply getting the answer to their question.  People post vague and incomplete questions because they don't know how to post good questions, don't know they're expected to post good questions, or don't want to take the time to post good questions, not because they're trying to prevent people from having enough information to figure out what they're actually asking.

Comment: I sometimes add "try this" because you cant *ever* be sure your code or answer will work in their situation without sitting in their seat. You cannot possibly have all the required data and variables at your exposure to give a 100% confident answer.

Comment: Seems more like a pet peeve than a legitimate constructive issue

Comment: Since "try this + code dump" is already considered acceptable (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284563/reduce-try-this-answers-by-giving-a-helpful-message) I don't see how making it cover more answers would get more acceptance... (anyway I've edited post to make it clear that scope is different from suggested duplicate... in future link to suggested duplicate in your edit because there is no way to know what you are disagreeing with)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flag 'Try This: {code}' Answers as "Very Low Quality"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality)

Answer (score 18):

From one angle, you could see "try this" as an **explicit** disclaimer for the code you are now copying and pasting into your project; that is to say, assuming that it will work and solve all of your problems without ever having to actually think about what it's doing is foolish.

From another angle, it is often how those who are in IT communicate on problem solving.  Most things *can* be performed through trial and error, and simply stating the obvious in trial isn't necessarily a bad thing in my mind.