# Unaccepted answer for something really close to my answer

Tags: discussion

I know this can be normal user behavior, but my answer was unaccepted yesterday for another answer posted after mine.

*[Button fill div height using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162294/bootstrap-button-fill-div-height/36162561#36162561)*

IMO: My answer is closer to the question, because it used the same CSS. The second answer adds some CSS (100% width and/or height).

This is not a complaint, but this lead me to the reflexion. If I have many questions on Stack Overflow and a friend of mine wants to get fast reputation points, I can unaccept all the previous answers to give him all the credits after he copy and paste the previous accepted answer, and then add a few modifications like this: *[Button fill div height using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162294/bootstrap-button-fill-div-height/36162561#36162561)*.

Do we have a moderating options for this?

Comment: Yes there are moderation options for people committing voting fraud.  Someone choosing not to accept your answer isn't voting fraud though.

Comment: My answer as been accepted for weeks, and just changed yesterday, seems strange to me.
Yes this is not voting fraud, but at least unfair :P

Comment: Thx for the edit :)

Comment: That your answer was accepted for a few weeks doesn't mean the author is prohibited from changing the accepted answer.  It's not unfair at all.  They feel that another answer was better, they accepted that answer instead.  That's not unfair at all.  Note that "unfair" and, "something that I personally don't like" are two very different things.  That you don't like that someone choose not to accept your answer doesn't make it unfair.  It's perfectly fair.

Comment: I would totally agree with you if the differences where huge or critical related to the question.
This is not the case at all.
Anyway this is not the main point of my post, not about what it seems fair or not. 
Your first answer about voting was perforct for me :)

Comment: Side note, if you see evidence of two user accounts colluding to inflate their reputation score, flag any of their posts, select "other" and enter a full description of what you think they're doing and any evidence to support it.  Mods have tools that will tell them if two or more users are inflating each other's reputation.

Comment: Side note: you answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36162561/477420 is of low quality due to lack of explanation what needs to be done. "Try this" is generally not considered good enough explanation of the solution. Try this - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality

Comment: Will's right, but in this case I don't see any evidence that these two users even know each other. Don't know why the accept vote was changed, but I don't think voting fraud is involved.

Comment: The question was bumped by a new answer. I wonder if the asker had the answers sorted in a way that prioritized the other answer over the then-accepted answer, leading the asker to conclude that they had somehow forgotten to accept an answer (which is not the case) and accept that other answer, ironically having forgotten that they *did* accept an answer much like it (with the exception of an inexplicably missing image from the HTML...).

Comment: Also note that when the OP accepted your answer they said it was, "Close enough" and that they had to edit it. Perhaps the new answer worked without additional edits.

Comment: @BoltClock The new answer is also arguably more helpful. Personally, I think `All you have to do is change the div with the class "row" to the height you want.` is much clearer and more instructive than `Are you looking for a result like this?`.

Comment: @Ed Cottrell: Yeah. The same reason can probably be used to explain why the accepted answer was only changed after so long - the asker just never noticed it the first time.

Comment: @StephenRauch Not a dupe. That question asks if you can unmark/mark new; this question asks about prevention misuse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general if this happens it is ok to spend some time checking if two accounts have suspicious relation (i.e. most posts are coming in pairs). If you feel that you have evidence of vote fraud - flag question as "require moderator attention" and provide details.

In this particular case there does not seem to be any evidence of fraud and new answer is simply better as it includes explanation of the solution instead of code dump. [Try this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=try+this) and similar text in most cases does not provide good enough explanation (especially when answer simply contains copy-paste of OP's wall of text with presumably some minor change).