# Should I flag code only answers as low quality posts?

Tags: discussion

Taking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44544218/4746087) example, where it's very hard to tell what the difference is with the OP's snippet, should I flag a code only answer as low quality too, or only downvote it and add a comment to ask for some clarification?

Comment: Related post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-ver%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8By-low-quality

Comment: No, you should not.

Comment: No. Similarly, if you come across a post like this in the LQP review queue "looks okay" is almost always the right option. These post aren't absolute garbage that needs to be deleted asap, which is what the VLQ flag is for.

Comment: Also see [Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764): **Use VLQ for obvious, unarguable *garbage***. Just code is an unhelpful answer, and not garbage.