# Why are code-only answers not considered "very low quality"?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

I flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213640/phpexcel-creates-multiple-worksheets/45434772#45434772) as "very low quality" because it is a code snippet without any explanation. However, my flag was disputed.

Can anybody explain why code-only answers are not "very low quality"?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350702/should-i-flag-code-only-answers-as-low-quality-posts#comment481867_350702

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue

Comment: Why was it "disputed"? Because [three users disagreed with your flag and said it "Looks OK" in the Low Quality review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16896057). Since you have 20k+ reputation, you can easily avoid this risk again in the future by downvoting the answer and casting a vote to delete it.

Comment: Whoa -- the new moderators are here! Congrats, and thanks!

Comment: Code-only? Hm would that apply to well-commented code? To code with really nice and sel-explaining variable and method nams? To Replace '..this..' by '..that..'? I'd say it really depends!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't make a blanket statement like, "If I see a code-only answer, it must always be low quality due to being code-only". Sometimes, in the context of the question itself, short snippets of code can be extremely helpful.

The answer you linked to was *not* helpful in the context of the question. In fact, as written, it was barely relevant. But that doesn't mean all answers that contain little more than code are the same - it depends on the answer.

Did the answer help you understand the problem being described in the question? If so, it's not low quality.

Comment: Ok. I agree with you. But mostly code with many lines is hard to understand without any comment.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, code-only answers are VLQ here, because the SO is not a code snippet sharing site. We use meaningful, well-formulated, human communication to share our thoughts. It is a much higher level of the communication, as writing a question on a semi-literate level, and then answering it with a code snippet.

Typically beginner programmers tend to think, that communicating purely in code snippets is a HQ thing, but it is not. In our minds, there are still human concepts and human terminology. We are thinking on a human language. Communicating in source code is not an advanced level of communication, it is a degradation of it.

*Not* doing with code-only answers anything (at least voting them down, or flagging them as VLQ if they seem unsalvageable) [breaks windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory), i.e. it encourages others (typically VLQ posters) to follow this bad behavior.

The StackExchange does a pretty amazing job to enforce these "young titans" to learn to formulate in round, natural language sentences, if they missed to learn this skill in the elementary school.

Comment: VLQ has a very specific meaning; a meaning that a code only answer doesn't meet.  You might think that it's a low quality answer, and therefore decide to downvote it, and that's frequently going to be appropriate, but it's going to be *very* rare for such an answer to merit deletion.

Comment: @Servy Okay, I edited the post. How about now?

Comment: @peterh No, it's still saying that code only answers merit flagging as VLQ, and that's almost never going to be the case.  VLQ isn't for answers that you don't like, or think are bad, it's for answers that have *nothing of value in them* and that are *entirely unsalvageable*, which is basically never true of a code only answer, because you can always add the missing explanation to the code to salvage it.

Comment: @Servy My experience is that code-only answers have often also other major problems, what can be fixed only by fixing the code. Or by deleting the post (for example, if they solve a different problem). They tend to have major problems in the readibility/clarity line, too. The central point of the sentence is that letting them as they are is not okay. What exactly has to be done with them, is not a central point. I edit the post again.

Comment: @peterh The central point of the question is whether or not a VLQ flag is merited, and the answer is *they aren't*.  Sure, *something* should probably be done, but that "something" *isn't* to flag it as VLQ.  That's an improper flag.

Comment: *what can be fixed only by fixing the code* - That just makes the answer wrong. It doesn't mean it's not an attempt to answer at all.

Comment: @BSMP Plus it's weird English :P

Comment: @Clonkex And still this is my opinion, with my weird English. What do you think, how can it be possible?