# When is an answer considered low quality?

Tags: discussion, flags, review-audits

I came across [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/19635868) in the late answers reviews.

The answer is very incorrect, but is also definitely an answer and shouldn't be flagged as "Not an Answer" according to [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) which makes the think it was removed for being "low quality".

According to an [answer by Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354282/9614249):

> Did the answer help you understand the problem being described in the question? If so, it's not low quality.

But that seems a little vague and open to interpretation.

Is there a concrete set of guidelines for what constitutes a low quality answer?

Comment: that's an endless debate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The criteria for a "Very Low Quality" flag is:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

It's the description displayed in the flagging dialog.

The answer used in the audit was, in fact, originally flagged by a user as "Very Low Quality," not "Not an Answer."

Consider its content:

> you'll have to drop `<!doctype html>`

OK, why?  How does that solve whatever the OP's problem is?  Even someone with only rudimentary skills in HTML would be compelled to respond to such a post with "You're saying that I have to abandon the doctype completely?  There better be a damn good reason."

Since the poster provided no explanation, there's no way for anyone else to divine his intent, and therefore no way to improve his post via editing.  Ergo, "Very Low Quality."