# Can someone explain why my review decisions (which led to a suspension) were wrong?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, low-quality-posts, review-suspension

Today I visited Stack Overflow and learned my review privileges have been suspended until Nov 13th.

I just started reviewing close votes and low quality answers last week as I earned the privilege.

When checking the suspension there is a list of five reviews that were handled incorrectly:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30262542
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30264390
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30264761
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30264962
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30265820

When checking the reviews, two of them do not make sense (while I totally understand why the others are incorrect - I am just learning how to properly handle those queues):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30262542

I flagged this as "recommend deletion". Two other users flagged it as "Delete". Mano and Zoe reviewed this answer as "ok".

So three out of five reviews indicate it should be deleted, yet this review counts as "incorrect" and counts towards my suspension(?).

Even more confusing is *https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30265820*.

Four people reviewed this, two as "recommend deletion", two as "delete".

Based upon that, the answer has been deleted.
So for me, this looks like I handled this correctly (as everyone else was thinking the same) and the answer *is* deleted, but still, this is shown as handled "incorrectly" and part of my suspension.

So I got suspended while two of five reviews leading to the suspension are at least disputable while one does not make sense for me at all.

Why do I think those are to be considered "low quality"?

Both posts basically consist of code-only without any explanations. They do not add any additional information or knowledge which isn’t contained in other answers on that question. So overall they do not improve the quality of the question or resolve the question. So I believe both of them are to be considered low quality answers.

Could anyone explain how those two are handled "incorrectly" and how the proper way would've been?

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30262542, it _does_ look like an answer. May or may not further explanation which is not really taken into account in lqp queue

Comment: No. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354280/why-are-code-only-answers-not-considered-very-low-quality and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue

Comment: Why would you delete a valid code suggestion that might solve the problem? If you think it is not useful, not correct or requires more explanation - downvote and leave a comment. We don't delete honest attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: LQP queue is for *very* low quality posts, essentially spam, gibberish, unintelligible English or non-English language, and questions/answers that should have been the other or a comment. Code only answers, link only answers, or answers that don't adequately answer the question or are outright incorrect are low quality but do not meet the *very* low quality threshold. For cases like these, this is what downvotes and post comments are meant for, because these are likely salvageable by the post author.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest small nitpick. "Link only" do go below the low quality threshold [in most cases](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/4826457).

Comment: It's important to realize that all "code only" answers get placed in the low quality review since they are by default bad questions. But most of the time they do attempt to answer the question and shouldn't be deleted (but just down-voted). The only case when such an answer should be deleted is what it's blatantly off-topic - lets say the question was about Java but someone posts a code-only C solution out of the blue.

Comment: Anyway, it would seem that you got banned for approving "apply code formatting to random nouns" vandalizing edits. These should be rejected and you can also check if the person who suggested such an edit has a history of doing such vandalism - in which case you might want to escalate that to the moderators.

Comment: @SurajRao Fair enough, I was limited by character count in the comment but yeah there is some nuance there. I was just trying to draw the line between a bad post that does attempt to answer a question which should be *downvoted* and a post that truly should be deleted.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your review suspension was manually imposed by a moderator. The decisions of other users on the review task are irrelevant—for all you know, they were suspended for making the wrong choices, too. You should not judge the correctness of your review decisions by the votes of other users, or even the eventual outcome of the review task. Instead, you need to find some objective criteria by which to judge the correctness of your review. Although you were working primarily in the Low Quality Posts review queue, I think [our advice on reviewing Late Answers and First Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-the-late-answers-and-first-questions-answers) would still be very useful.

Going through the specific review tasks:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30262542

  This was a legitimate attempt to answer the question and it should not be deleted. Therefore, your decision to recommend deletion was incorrect.

  Now, granted, when you saw that review item, you *should* have immediately been suspect that it was "not an answer". The use of the phrase "worked for me!" is often a clue that someone is regurgitating a previous answer and, essentially, saying "thanks". It is correct to delete such "thanks" answers. So, upon seeing this, you should have immediately opened the full Q&A to review the other answers. Upon seeing no other answer that contained the same solution as jokermt235's answer, you would have known that it was not a "thanks" answer and that it should not have been deleted.

  Personally, I would still not have chosen "Looks OK". Instead, I would have edited the answer to make it clear that it is *not* a "thanks" answer. This not only presents better on the site, but it also avoids tripping up future reviewers.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30264390

  This suggested edit was tantamount to vandalism. It did nothing whatsoever to improve the post's quality or presentation. All it did was add inline code formatting to random words, many of which were not even code (e.g., "components").

  This is a common problem with suggested edits, so it's something you need to watch out for as a reviewer. It is called out specifically in [our FAQ on editing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219), in the section "Use inline code formatting only for code". Note that even when the items are actually identifiers in code, inline code formatting should still be used sparingly, as it often makes the post more difficult to read. Adding *only* inline code formatting to a post is almost never a useful edit—*i.e.*, even if not vandalism, it should at least be rejected on the grounds that it provides no improvement.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30264761

  This edit also needed to be rejected for two reasons:

  1. The edit changed the code style for no reason. The use of `array()` in preference to `[]` can be found in the question itself, not to mention the other answer, so I cannot see why it would be appropriate to arbitrarily change this in one of the answers. Furthermore, no justification was offered for why this is preferable or why the current code doesn't work. One should be reluctant to change (or approve changes in) code in posts, unless that person is a subject-matter expert who can personally vouch for the correctness of the edits.
  2. The edit claimed to "format code", but this is incorrect. All it did was add a syntax highlighting hint, but that syntax highlighting hint is completely pointless in this case, as the question is tagged [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), which means that all code snippets are defaulting to PHP syntax highlighting already.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30264962

  Like the earlier edit, this edit does nothing whatsoever to improve the post and arguably makes it worse. All it does is add inline code formatting to things that aren't code. ReactJS is the name of a framework; it is definitely not code. And while it might be defensible to format file names as code in certain cases (e.g., to emphasize that embedded spaces are part of the same name), there was no reason to do so here.

  Also, this edit failed to remove the "Thanks!!" from the bottom of the post, which is a pretty significant omission on the part of the editor. Thus, even if we ignore the incorrect application of inline code formatting to "ReactJS" and concede that it is acceptable to apply inline code formatting to file names, we're still left with an edit that provides no measurable improvement and overlooks *obvious* problems.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30265820

  This is the exact same situation as the very first bullet point here.

Comment: Nicely explained, as always... Small correction/hint: In the first bullet - *"you should have immediately opened the full Q&A to review the other answers"* - not even necessary! For that we have the "Other Answers" tab in the review to quickly check....... the other answers...

Comment: Would that not be a way to achieve opening the full Q&A, @Tomerikoo? :-) But, yes, my clear bias for reviewing posts in the same format that I normally see them on the site sneaks in. I always open the full Q&A in a new tab. It is not required to do so, but I think it makes it much easier to judge context and preserve muscle memory.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I've seen "Other answers" tab empty during audits, whereas there were other answers...

Comment: Just, where can we found our review like that: the one that we voted for, that are not audit and our vote is different from other (and so can be reason for review ban) ?

Comment: @Elikill58 You can see all of your reviews [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10952503/elikill58?tab=activity&sort=reviews). However, as I mention at the very top of this answer, it is not sufficient (and may even be misleading) to simply compare your decision to the majority vote. Plenty of reviewers make wrong decisions in review queues. If you are suspended from reviewing, the suspension message will include a link to the review tasks that you reviewed incorrectly. That's how Fabian got this list, which he shared in his question.

Comment: Thanks ! But we can't see review audit (even failed one). We can't sort or filter them

Comment: @Elikill58 I believe you can also use [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/history?userId=10952503&skipped=true). You'll need to do some URL manipulation to change to different review queues, though. I'm not sure if that view is any better.

Comment: @CodyGray We can't see if it's review or not ?