# Code fragment as an answer, when the question didn't ask for code

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296863/4350586) question reads

> What is difference between `wait` and `sleep`?

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13301329/4350586) answer is

> Try this: `sleep 10 & wait %1`

I flagged this as NAA, and my flag got declined.

Now, I'm trying to improve my flagging behavior and understand what I did wrong, but I honestly cannot identify a single bit of information in it which relates to the question. There is no technical inaccuracies in it, and it isn't wrong, it simply doesn't answer the question at all.

Any thoughts?

If this answer should stay, should we also allow answers suggesting to "google `wait`" or RTFM? As far as my understanding goes, those would actually be better, because they get you much closer to the information you need than a command which simply returns after 10 seconds.

Comment: @SurajRao Care to explain why the flag was declined then? I read that post already and still don't understand how this would qualify as an answer.

Comment: It is still an attempt to answer the question through sample code. Check the answer by @Erik

Comment: Don't expect reviewers of NAA flags to know anything about programming, logic, or the English language. Well, maybe English insofar as they need to recognize what's not valid English. But that's it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I fail to read this as an answer even considering English language alone. I.e. "The difference between `wait` and `sleep` is... try this"?

Comment: "Try this" is valid English, and is used in 80% of the answers on Stack Overflow. The rest is formatted as code and is therefore not English. See [Flag 'Try This: {code}' Answers as "Very Low Quality"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359) for more discussion on that. Basically, in order for a NAA flag to be marked helpful, it has to be gobbledygook or obviously a new question. See the duplicate for an extended discussion, or just look at questions tagged [meta-tag:not-an-answer] for a rich history.

Comment: NAA flag and LQ queue has a low bar on what constitutes a valid flag. Use downvotes for the rest

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I believe that question refers to 'Try This: {code}' answers to question which actually ask for code.

Comment: Similar to rhetorical questions, right?

Comment: @Heretic "Try this" makes sense as an answer to a "How do I ... ?" question. It doesn't make sense as an answer to a "What is the difference between X and Y?" question.

Comment: @LarsH Well, a year ago, when this conversation was fresh, I might’ve has some pithy comeback. As it is, all I can say is to read the answer to this meta question. And again, read the other meta questions with the tag to see the history of the flag.

Comment: @Heretic I have read the answer to this meta question. But my comment above was specifically in response to your comment about "try this" being used in "80% of the answers on SO": code is a helpful response to certain common *types* of questions, and not to others. So the fact that code is a valid answer for many questions may be irrelevant to a question of another type. However I realize I'm late to this part of the discussion and am not expecting others to resurrect it for my sake. There are also many other parts of the discussion that I'm not trying to address in the above comment.

Comment: @LarsH Sure, but the fact that a particular answer type is not helpful or is irrelevant to the question type is itself irrelevant to the NAA flag. The answer *is an answer*, however unhelpful or irrelevant its type may be. If it's unhelpful, downvote it. If its type is irrelevant, downvote it. The Not an Answer flag is solely for those pieces of text entered in the answer box which are not answers to *any* question at all.

Comment: Really? So "Tuesday" is an answer to "What's the price of tea in China?" That would make NAA a pretty useless tag, when it would be very useful to have a way to mark "answers" that don't attempt to answer the question asked. However, I am traipsing into territory that seems to be deeper than I want to take time to fully read up on. So feel free to ignore my reaction.

Comment: An example I've seen of something that is not an answer is "I have the same problem, but this solution doesn't work for me.  Why doesn't it work in this scenario? <scenario description>"

Answer (score 6):

A code answer to a question asking the difference between two functions can be a good answer, as it can demonstrate it.

Any attempt to answer the question is **not** NAA. If the question is bad, you might want to address that, instead of the answer.

Comment: Yes, a code answer may be a good answer. I don't understand what *this particular answer* demonstrates.

Comment: Well, it does show you that both functions take a different kind of parameters, and running it might show you they behave differently, but I certainly don't think it's a _good_ answer. That's enough to make it not count as NAA, though.

Comment: I don't see a difference with a link-only answer: the actual answer to the question is elsewhere.

Comment: Link-only answers are very specific things. They're not allowed for multiple reasons, such as being a risk for spam (links may contain ads), a risk of the link expiring, and more. While a link-only answer may be way more helpful than this one, they're not allowed, while answers such as this one are.

Comment: This particular example only shows that one of them will cause wait for 1 second. After reading the code, it is completely unclear which one does, and even misleading. Examining the code, and executing it provides not helpful information. A more helpful answer has two different pieces of code, which only differ by the use of wait/sleep, which exposes the difference.