# Someone deleted the question which I answered and got up-votes

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I answered one question and got 3 upvotes, but someone deleted the question and I lost the reputation points.

When I tried to delete a question of mine which someone else answered, Stack Overflow said you can't delete question because someone has put effort for this question. Why?

Comment: You should be able to see the question and answers if you have a link to it. Check your browser history.

Comment: by any luck, was the question an off-topic one? a simple typo issue? opnion based?

Comment: If the question was closed because it was deemed off-topic, [users with 10k or more rep can vote to delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: Question was similar to another question, but me and some other people answered, but later question was deleted. My doubt is if that question can be deleted then why can't i delete my own question which somebody else answered?@TemaniAfif

Comment: @Athira it's literally the difference between how the delete votes work. It stops users from abusing the site and deleting content with good answers.

Comment: @Athira side note: please check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256402/477420 which talks about "try this code" answers.

Answer (score 7):

Users cannot delete questions they've posted once the question receives upvoted answers. So that is why you've had this issue in the past. Users with delete vote privileges can use them to vote to delete questions that have been closed.

There is only [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53517387/3956566) you posted with three upvotes that has been deleted.

The question had been deleted by people in the community, as it has been closed as a duplicate.

*Personally I am not in agreement with deleting duplicate questions with decent answers, they all help search engine results and sometimes an answer on a duplicate question will help someone who is really struggling and just needs to see something explained or written in another way. But I will step in line with community census on this.*

---

Due to wise peer pressure I've redeleted the question. As my peers pointed out to me, and rightly so, the question was not a good duplicate, due to the lack of research effort shown by the questioner.

Let this be a lesson to the people who answered it to not waste time answering questions that show little effort. Instead focus on the better quality questions.

Comment: It wouldn't even make sense so save a duplicate question just to protect the answers. If you like the answers, then move them to the dupe target, but don't keep the question if it isn't suitable as a sign post. And since all three answers were mostly code without much explanation I wouldn't even be in favor of migrating/moving them to the other question.

Comment: @Tom yes, that's what we have merge for.  We don't use the merge feature lightly. They need to be exactly duplicated.

Comment: Instead of deleting a low quality question, another good option is to edit the question so that it is no longer of low quality. Especially if it has a good answer underneath it.

Comment: @AlexHarvey fwiw I deleted your meta post, as I didn't see the comment thread as leading to anything constructive. It was not personal to you in particular.

Comment: That's ok @YvetteColomb. I'll just reprogram myself as a bot with more enthusiasm for deleting the work of others.

Comment: That's not a comment on you, btw. I agree that was going nowhere useful. :)

Comment: @AlexHarvey I did notice the irony in closing a post for not seeking input or discussion, yet a massive comment thread under the post discussing it :) Perhaps consider coming back with a new question, phrasing it a little differently. If you want some pointers on how to fare better on meta, I'm happy to help.