# Is an opinion or assumption-based answer eligible for being "Not an answer" (NAA)?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, opinion-based, answer-quality

I recently came across a couple of answers which rather almost entirely consist of assumptions or opinions than are based upon facts. Often answered to off-topic questions like seeking for recommendations or being opinion-based as well.

F.e.:

> "I do not think that .... is available for ....".

OR

> ".... might cause this behavior, but I don't know for sure.".

I flagged an answer in the former style for being NAA as I thought it would better be a comment and it got declined.

Are opinion or assumption-based answers treated as usual answers?

And does it make a difference whether the question is off-topic (seeking for recommendations, opinion-based etc.) or not? Is it explicitly allowed in such cases that opinions or assumptions are an answer?

---

I've read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/12139179) that "an attempt to answer a question" classifies not being eligible for NAA, but is it OK to use opinions or assumptions as answer just because they "*attempt*" to answer the question?

Comment: They are not NAA if they *try* to answer the question (even if just guessing or the question's closed). They may be of low quality and should perhaps be downvoted.

Comment: Thanks, @gnat but I've already read that post (as you also can see form my comments there). My question is whether the "*attempt to answer the question*" as stated in the linked answer weighs more than to just dump an assumption or opinion which is against the rules in case of questions. Is it OK to just use opinions or assumptions as answer just because it attempts to answer the question?

Comment: The Question make some Answers, not "No an Answer". If the Question asks for a link, then a link-only Answer is really just answering it. The "should be a comment" is not really all that applicable when talking about flagging as "Not an Answer" in my experience. Guesses are attempts to answer, so they're not flaggable.

Comment: @JeanneDark Thank you. But that raises another question - in the case of being low quality is the post then eligible for flagging as VLQ (Very low quality)?

Comment: VLQ: [The post is an indecipherable mess and can't be salvaged in the amount of time we're prepared to ask our users to spend editing a single post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167641)

Comment: it's not OK but not bad enough to justify mod flag - neither NAA, nor VLQ, nor custom... unfortunately. Similar matters were discussed in [Flag 'Try This: {code}' Answers as “Very Low Quality”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/839601)

Comment: The only real difference between NAA and VLQ flags are that NAA flags are persistent. VLQ flags will be dismissed (I believe as helpful) by an edit to the post.

Comment: So, again, I disagreed with the duplicate. There isn't any reference to vague statements. If anything, gnat's post is related.

Answer (score 11):

Please leave answers that preface with or contain explicit uncertainty alone.

It is good that the answerer states that they aren't a hundred percent sure that their answer is correct, but it can help the OP and later visitors along.

*"I'm not sure you can do that with library X, but library Y has a function to..."* is a perfectly valid answer.

An answer solely stating *"I don't think that's possible"* is as bad as a *"That's not possible"* without a source. Both are answers as far as the rules are concerned, but not very good answers. They can't be flagged, but can be downvoted and possibly deleted when they reach the threshold enabling that.

Comment: So I just use downvoting if the guess is incorrect (when I'm subject-matter experienced to the topic) but no flag?

Comment: "but library Y has a function to" it's an assertion. Here we are discussing answers that are just guesses without any shred of certainty.

Answer (score 3):

There are many answers which says

> Maybe you should try...

> If you are doing this ... then try this ...

> Did you try this...? This seems missing...

Raising Flags on these type of answers will get declined with a message

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
> inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

All of these are valid attempts to answer a question and most of the time made by new contributors. In my opinion, not flagging these answers is the right thing to do.

If I am a subject matter expert of a specific tag and I know that this answer is correct, I would sometimes go ahead and edit it that it sound like a more confident answer.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the moderator, they could see it as an "attempt to answer a question", but personally I expect answers to be at least educated guesses, so such answers should be edited to make the post assert their statements. You can theorically fix these posts, but sometimes there's just too much work arguing for the answer that you could instead answer the question yourself. I have examples where I did exactly this, the [answer guessed (incorrectly) that the command has a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62391941/792066) where I wrote an answer with the assertion of the expected behavior of the command with enough evidence to do so.

Comment: So in order to post your opinion as an answer you reopened this question, yet you don't even answer the question? Bravo.

Comment: @Tom Funny enough, the first sentence *is* an answer although it is an assumption. ;-)

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio The first sentence just repeats what a "decline" on your flag already tells you.

Comment: @Tom I'm asserting that that depends on the moderator, that's a **educated guess**, considering that some moderators even disagree publicly on the current handling of NAA flags.

Comment: If they disagree with the current handling or not _should_ not matter in how they handle these flags right now. If it does, then those are pretty bad mods and should be removed from their positions. There are process in order to change the handling of "things" and if they want to change those processes, then this must be requested and discussed. Mods are not above that

Comment: @Tom oh, so you want all but one moderator removed? SE employees themselves disagree with how SO mods handle NAA, and moderators from other SE sites do too. BTW, the post that people keeps reffering to only tries to get people stopping flagging wrong questions as NAA. That everyone agree, just that they took it way too far as "anything in the answer box can be an answer".

Comment: Every mod, except one, SE employees and mods from other sites think that those flags are handled incorrectly, but no one bothered to change that. Is this summed up correctly?

Comment: @Tom because they don't want to start a very public, very nasty holy war. Shog was on the side of smart fighting (putting nuggets of wisdom, like the castle/apple analogy), other are in the avoid causing the fallout camp. Remember that SE corp burned a lot of good will, and sadly moderators aren't seen as public servants (which they actually are) and more of a god-like figure, so they carry too much weight.