# Can we edit a question to include additional information from discussion chat?

Tags: discussion, questions, chat

I was in a discussion with the original poster of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172081/how-can-i-do-mysql-query-to-find-a-user-everytime-he-is-logged-on-a-table-and-a/) and there was additional information added during the chat. After the chat ended, I edited the question but I didn't include the full additional information that we've discussed. Today I went to review the question again because I would like to see if I can re-construct the query in the answer that I posted to something better and I notice that there was a new answer posted. While the answer did solve the issue, the question wasn't including the latest information that was discussed in the chat. I guess that the OP should be responsible to update the question but since I already know the situation, I thought that I just edit the question and include the additional information.

Now I'm in a bit of a dilemma, part of me thinking that since the additional information was from the discussion then it shouldn't be wrong to edit into the question and another part of me is thinking otherwise. What would be the correct approach here?

For clarification, at the moment there are 2 answers on the question but none being accepted yet. I did post an answer according to the additional information from the discussion but end up deleting it due to the mismatch of operation with the original question. I guess that's why I decided to edit the question in the first place. So, I was wondering if the conditions/information that was added afterwards would be considered as invalidating the answers that have been posted, provided that at least one of the answer is correct.

Comment: That edit was a completely new question, you shouldn't have edited since there already were answers... I would suggest you should rollback and let the OP ask a new question.

Comment: Looks like your edit moved the goal post and invalidating current answers, which is frowned upon. If the additional information fixes the original problem, then it should be posted as an answer instead (if anyone else hasn't posted the same approach). But the follow-up questions are new, and they should be posted as a new question.

Comment: Got it @AndrewT. and @ AbdulAzizBarkat . I'll rollback the question and suggest OP to post a new question if needed.

Comment: @FaNo_FN but since it's a 'new' question, that does mean a new duplicate check needs to be performed first.

Comment: Yes @Gimby . I'm not sure if OP wants to open a new question though. During the discussion, OP did say that it was for a thesis so I assume it's a one time thing and not part of a real project.

Comment: However, in general, if new information is obtained via comments or chat, which clarify the question as is, then yes you should most definitely edit them in assuming OP doesn't (you can always encourage OP first if you wish).

Comment: You should not produce *chamelion* questions ([relevant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/299295) topic about them), nor post the answer into a question (edit was rolled back). The deleted answer is of low quality, basically "code-only" answer ([relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/1997232) topic about what to do with them).

Comment: That was my bad @Sinatr. I probably was thinking that since I've had a lengthy discussion with the OP, I might as well just post an answer (without explanation) at the end but I've "forgotten" that this is a Q&A site. I _usually try_ to be thorough with my answers though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can we edit a question to include additional information from discussion chat?

In general, yes. The author of the question should be editing their question themselves, to provide clarifications and other improvements requested in comments. But if in the comments, they share information that clarifies or otherwise improves the questions, and they don't put that information in the question themselves, it is fine to edit the question yourself to move that information to where it belongs.

That said…

> What would be the correct approach here?

In *this specific example*, it seems that you did not simply move clarifying information into the question, but instead introduced a completely new question to the post.

**Please don't do that.**

So-called ["Chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are a significant problem on Stack Overflow. They make it much more difficult for future readers to find the information they are looking for, and they often render already-posted answers irrelevant, or at the very least confusing.

In this specific example, you had a couple of options:

- Encourage the original author of the question to post a new question, based on the additional details provided in the comments, or…
- If you had a particular interest in the question itself, either because you wanted to know the answer or you felt there was a way to answer it in a way that contributed to the overall corpus of knowledge embodied by the site, you could post a new question yourself (and posting an answer to that new question, if you had an answer).

Comment: After reading a few more of the linked "chameleon question", I'm 100% confident that my edit was suppose to be an entirely new question. The example that struck me the most was when OP asks how to obtain a result based on a specific condition and once we've already had the answer to that, OP add another condition to it. I may have felt that since the operation is basically the same, it is still the same thing. However, the condition and expected outcome are already different. Thank you so much for the clarification.