# How should we respond to unclear questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, unclear

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How can I take a string in an integer input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75530897/how-to-take-string-in-an-integer-input-field/75531364#75531364)

The post asks about data type conversion. However, when I added an answer, I got a negative mark for that.

What is the better approach to handling ambiguous questions?

Comment: If it's unclear then flag as unclear. If it's about string -> integer conversion, then we *must* have a duplicate or probably four dozen. Find one and flag as a duplicate. If you do want to answer and it's a distinct issue not covered at least a hundred times, then at least add some explanation and references, not post essentially just code.

Comment: First of all if If the question is unclear then your answer is only you guessing.  Secondly SO is for high quality questions and answers.  By answering questions that do not meet this expectation, then you personally are actively making SO a worse place and downvotes on your answer are very appropriate.

Comment: Side note: the quality of a post like yours "try this" code-only answer is generally considered "very low" irrespective of the quality of the question - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality. You may want to start with fixing that part.

Comment: **Please** read [answer].

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're not reasonably confident about what the OP is asking, it's best to not answer the question.

The biggest reason is what you're being shown now - if you don't know what is being asked, you don't have a solid way of determining that your answer is correct or suitable, and you're left guessing and engaging in a conversation, which *isn't* really what we want.

So if you don't know what the OP is asking?  Just don't answer it!  When you get 50 rep you could comment and ask for clarifications.