# How can I find out why this flag was declined, when the question is deleted?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I raised a "not an answer flag" for this answer: [Remove line break from br for mobile/tablet devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76291609/remove-line-break-from-br-for-mobile-tablet-devices/76296644#76296644). I'm curious because it was the only flag of mine rejected this month. However, I can't see when I open the link. 
Since it was deleted, it makes me think that something should have been flagged there to begin with. On the other hand, it was the question, not the answer that was deleted. Is there a chance to find out what happened at this point?

Comment: It was deleted by author. Then they deleted the question too. It doesn't look like NAA so I don't know why you have flagged it.

Comment: Me neither, I can't remember at this point. How can I find this out?

Comment: i mean.. are you asking why you decided to flag it NAA? how can we know that?

Comment: My question is why I can't see it from the link and where can I see it?

Comment: because it's deleted and it isn't yours. You'd be able to see it by following the link if you had 10k rep

Comment: The answer was rather simple, if not a weird solution. "Created a custom tag:" followed by some css that styles a non-standard html element. Certainly not NAA.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> On the other hand it was the question, not the answer that was deleted. Any chance to find out what happened at this point?

The question was self-deleted, as the 404 page should indicate by saying "This question was voluntarily removed by its author". We can only speculate to why they self-deleted the question, but it has zero relevance to your flag being declined.

Deletion isn't always an indicator something should've been flagged, at least with the type of flag you've opted for on a given arbitrary answer. It can be, but there are many, many reasons for deletion, particularly self-deletion.

The answer in question for <10k users:

> [image: Screenshot showing the flagged (and now deleted) answer]

Also worth noting that the edit only cleaned up some whitespace, and did not change the answer from an NAA to an answer. The flag was raised after the edit anyway, so that's not really applicable. It's just an incorrect flag.

The answer is not particularly high-quality, but it does not meet any of the deletion criteria. It is an attempt to answer the question, demonstrating what they did to solve their problem. It doesn't include much of an explanation, [but that isn't required, nor flaggable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/6296561), and is a use-case for downvotes instead.

<sub>Note: I did not decline the flag, but I fully agree with the mod who did</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I'm not advocating to reinstate the flag, just trying to learn from past mistakes, which I couldn't before seeing your answer.